# Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?

Tags: python, debugging, introspection, pretty-print, python-datamodel

So what I'm looking for here is something like PHP's [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r) function.

This is so I can debug my scripts by seeing what's the state of the object in question.

Comment: You are asking for _attributes_, aren't you? The question is misleading, because _property_ has a specific meaning in Python which differs from the meaning of _attribute_. If I am right, maybe you want to rephrase your question?

Answer (score 807, accepted):

You are really mixing together two different things.

Use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) or the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to get what you are interested in (I use `__builtins__` as an example; you can use any object instead).

```
>>> l = dir(__builtins__)
>>> d = __builtins__.__dict__
```

Print that dictionary however fancy you like:

```
>>> print l
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError',...
```

or

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(l)
['ArithmeticError',
 'AssertionError',
 'AttributeError',
 'BaseException',
 'DeprecationWarning',
...

>>> pprint(d, indent=2)
{ 'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>,
  'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>,
  'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>,
...
  '_': [ 'ArithmeticError',
         'AssertionError',
         'AttributeError',
         'BaseException',
         'DeprecationWarning',
...
```

Pretty printing is also available in the interactive debugger as a command:

```
(Pdb) pp vars()
{'__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>,
                  'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>,
                  'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>,
                  'BaseException': <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>,
                  'BufferError': <type 'exceptions.BufferError'>,
                  ...
                  'zip': <built-in function zip>},
 '__file__': 'pass.py',
 '__name__': '__main__'}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, it seems not all objects have a `__dict__` member (an `re.MatchObject` for instance), but builtin `dir()` works for all objects.

Comment: `print re.compile(r'slots').search('No slots here either.').__slots__`

Comment: @hobs: you are aware that "confer!" means "see also", "compare"? I know that match objects have no slots. that's not the point i tried to make.

Comment: why don't you talk more about `inspect` module in your answer? I think it is the closest thing to print_r or var_dump.

Comment: The question isn't mixing two different things. The var function works as required: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/193539/revisions

Comment: How do you access the values behind the attributes listed by `dir()`, then? `dir()` only returns a list of names, and not all of those exist in `vars()` or in the `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: what do you mean "You are really mixing together two different things."?

Comment: Regarding the `inspect` module: The method is `inspect.getmembers`, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215609/5267751).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Sorry its a long time reply - not everything listed by dir() is an attribute. And not everything is in the __dict__ because of how slots work with optimised objects. But effectively, you can do a loop and do `callable(object, varname)` and if it's false, you can then do getattr on that to programmatically access. @tomasZubiri Vars() doesn't work always because of slots.

Answer (score 1364):

You want `vars()` mixed with `pprint()`:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(vars(your_object))
```

Comment: `vars()` simply returns the `__dict__` of its argument and that is also the fallback of `dir()` in case there is no `__dir__` method. so use `dir()` in the first place, as i said.

Comment: @hop: `dir()` gives you all the built in things you probably don't care about like `__str__` and `__new__`. `var()` doesn't.

Comment: This fails on sets and other objects that doesn't have `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: this is absolutely good anwers, adding more: from inspect import getmembers

Comment: @hop, `vars()` gives the values of the fields, while `dir()` leaves them a mystery.

Comment: str(pformat(vars(session)).encode('utf-8')).replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\t', '\t')  - dont kill me but with utf8 that what works

Comment: if there are other objects in the properties you can use `def nestvars(elem):
    if hasattr(elem, '__dict__'):
        return {k:nestvars(v) for (k,v) in vars(elem)}
    else:
        return elem` and then `nestvars(your_object)`

Answer (score 306):

```
def dump(obj):
  for attr in dir(obj):
    print("obj.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
```

There are many 3rd-party functions out there that add things like exception handling, national/special character printing, recursing into nested objects etc. according to their authors' preferences. But they all basically boil down to this.

Comment: unpythonic, because follows not-invented-here

Comment: Say what?  Sure, you can use the `getmembers()` function in the standard `inspect` module, but I thought this would be more useful in that it illustrates how to do introspection in general.

Comment: even then it sets a bad example, because you essentially reemplemented obj.__dict__ .

Comment: NOT AT ALL. dir(obj) shows properties that aren't found in `__dict__` (such as `__doc__` and `__module__`). Furthermore, `__dict__` doesn't work at all for objects declared with `__slots__`. In general, `__dict__` shows user-level properties that are actually stored in a dictionary internally. dir() shows more.

Comment: what are you talking about? both `__module__` and `__doc__` are in `__dict__`!

Comment: Some classes/objects don't contain any `__dict__` attribute/member. I know it's crazy, but true. Built-ins like `int` and `str` or `re.MatchObject`s are common examples. Try `'hello'.__dict__`, then try `dir('hello')`

Comment: Well, this answer at least prints _both_ attributes' names _and_ values, in case an object doesn't have a dict (like the return from, say, `QtGui.QMdiSubWindow.sizePolicy()`), which is what I like about it.

Answer (score 111):

`dir` has been mentioned, but that'll only give you the attributes' names.  If you want their values as well, try `__dict__`.

```
class O:
   def __init__ (self):
      self.value = 3

o = O()
```

Here is the output:

```
>>> o.__dict__

{'value': 3}
```

Comment: Objects like `set` doesn't have `__dict__`, so for them it will fail with `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Answer (score 82):

> ### Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?

No. The most upvoted answer excludes some kinds of attributes, and the accepted answer shows how to get *all* attributes, including methods and parts of the non-public api. But there is no good complete *builtin* function for this.

So the short corollary is that you can write your own, but it will calculate properties and other calculated data-descriptors that are part of the public API, and you might not want that:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from inspect import getmembers
from types import FunctionType

def attributes(obj):
    disallowed_names = {
      name for name, value in getmembers(type(obj)) 
        if isinstance(value, FunctionType)}
    return {
      name: getattr(obj, name) for name in dir(obj) 
        if name[0] != '_' and name not in disallowed_names and hasattr(obj, name)}

def print_attributes(obj):
    pprint(attributes(obj))
```

### Problems with other answers

Observe the application of the currently top voted answer on a class with a lot of different kinds of data members:

```py
from pprint import pprint

class Obj:
    __slots__ = 'foo', 'bar', '__dict__'
    def __init__(self, baz):
        self.foo = ''
        self.bar = 0
        self.baz = baz
    @property
    def quux(self):
        return self.foo * self.bar

obj = Obj('baz')
pprint(vars(obj))
```

only prints:

```py
{'baz': 'baz'}
```

Because `vars` *only* returns the `__dict__` of an object, and it's not a copy, so if you modify the dict returned by vars, you're also modifying the `__dict__` of the object itself.

```py
vars(obj)['quux'] = 'WHAT?!'
vars(obj)
```

returns:

```py
{'baz': 'baz', 'quux': 'WHAT?!'}
```

-- which is bad because quux is a property that we shouldn't be setting and shouldn't be in the namespace...

Applying the advice in the currently accepted answer (and others) is not much better:

```
>>> dir(obj)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'quux']
```

As we can see, `dir` only returns *all* (actually just most) of the names associated with an object.

`inspect.getmembers`, mentioned in the comments, is similarly flawed - it returns all names *and* values.

#### From class

When teaching I have my students create a function that provides the semantically public API of an object:

```py
def api(obj):
    return [name for name in dir(obj) if name[0] != '_']
```

We can extend this to provide a *copy* of the semantic namespace of an object, but we need to exclude `__slots__` that aren't assigned, and if we're taking the request for "current properties" seriously, we need to exclude calculated properties (as they could become expensive, and could be interpreted as not "current"):

```py
from types import FunctionType
from inspect import getmembers

def attrs(obj):
    disallowed_properties = {
        name for name, value in getmembers(type(obj)) 
        if isinstance(value, (property, FunctionType))
    }
    return {
        name: getattr(obj, name) for name in api(obj) 
        if name not in disallowed_properties and hasattr(obj, name)
    }
```

And now we do not calculate or show the property, quux:

```
>>> attrs(obj)
{'bar': 0, 'baz': 'baz', 'foo': ''}
```

#### Caveats

But perhaps we do know our properties aren't expensive. We may want to alter the logic to include them as well. And perhaps we want to exclude *other* **custom** data descriptors instead.

Then we need to further customize this function. And so it makes sense that we cannot have a built-in function that magically knows exactly what we want and provides it. This is functionality we need to create ourselves.

### Conclusion

There is no built-in function that does this, and you should do what is most semantically appropriate for your situation.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/beeprint (or https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint) pretty prints 'everything' and also recursively.

Comment: that what for parameters to get customized thing from a function

Comment: @NZD not works for `from collections import * ;
obj=Counter([3,4])`

Answer (score 36):

You can use the "dir()" function to do this.

```
>>> import sys
>>> dir(sys)
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdo
t__', '_current_frames', '_getframe', 'api_version', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder
, 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dllhandle', 'exc_clear', 'exc_info'
 'exc_type', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefault
ncoding', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getwindowsversion', 'he
version', 'maxint', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_
ache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'ps1', 'ps2', 'setcheckinterval', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit
, 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoption
', 'winver']
>>>
```

Another useful feature is help.

```
>>> help(sys)
Help on built-in module sys:

NAME
    sys

FILE
    (built-in)

MODULE DOCS
    http://www.python.org/doc/current/lib/module-sys.html

DESCRIPTION
    This module provides access to some objects used or maintained by the
    interpreter and to functions that interact strongly with the interpreter.

    Dynamic objects:

    argv -- command line arguments; argv[0] is the script pathname if known
```

Answer (score 27):

To print the current state of the object you might:

```
>>> obj # in an interpreter
```

or

```
print repr(obj) # in a script
```

or

```
print obj
```

For your classes define `__str__` or `__repr__` methods. From the [Python documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/customization.html):

> `__repr__(self)` Called by the `repr()` built-in function and by string
>   conversions (reverse quotes) to
>   compute the "official" string
>   representation of an object. If at all
>   possible, this should look like a
>   valid Python expression that could be
>   used to recreate an object with the
>   same value (given an appropriate
>   environment). If this is not possible,
>   a string of the form "<...some useful
>   description...>" should be returned.
>   The return value must be a string
>   object. If a class defines **repr**()
>   but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is
>   also used when an "informal" string
>   representation of instances of that
>   class is required. This is typically
>   used for debugging, so it is important
>   that the representation is
>   information-rich and unambiguous.
>
> `__str__(self)` Called by the `str()` built-in function and by the print
>   statement to compute the "informal"
>   string representation of an object.
>   This differs from `__repr__()` in that
>   it does not have to be a valid Python
>   expression: a more convenient or
>   concise representation may be used
>   instead. The return value must be a
>   string object.

Comment: This option is useful for printing strings concatenated with the content of the object: `print "DEBUG: object value: " + repr(obj)`

Answer (score 21):

I recommend using `help(your_object)`.

`help(dir)`

> ```
>  If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
>  Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
>  of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
>  If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise
>  the default dir() logic is used and returns:
>  for a module object: the module's attributes.
>  for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
>  of its bases.
>  for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
>  recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
> ```

`help(vars)`

> ```
> Without arguments, equivalent to locals().
> With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__.
> ```

Answer (score 20):

Might be worth checking out --

[Is there a Python equivalent to Perl's Data::Dumper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540567/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-perls-datadumper)

My recommendation is this --

https://gist.github.com/1071857

Note that perl has a module called Data::Dumper which translates object data back to perl source code (NB: it does NOT translate code back to source, and almost always you don't want to the object method functions in the output). This can be used for persistence, but the common purpose is for debugging.

There are a number of things standard python pprint fails to achieve, in particular it just stops descending when it sees an instance of an object and gives you the internal hex pointer of the object (errr, that pointer is not a whole lot of use by the way). So in a nutshell, python is all about this great object oriented paradigm, but the tools you get out of the box are designed for working with something other than objects.

The perl Data::Dumper allows you to control how deep you want to go, and also detects circular linked structures (that's really important). This process is fundamentally easier to achieve in perl because objects have no particular magic beyond their blessing (a universally well defined process).

Comment: > So in a nutshell, python is all about this great object oriented paradigm, but the tools you get out of the box are designed for working with something other than objects... Quite a claim when the only example you're providing is a module of secondary importance.

Comment: @memeplex where does it say python is **all about** OOP?

Comment: this is only for 2.7

Answer (score 15):

In most cases, using `__dict__` or `dir()` will get you the info you're wanting. If you should happen to need more details, the standard library includes the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module, which allows you to get some impressive amount of detail. Some of the real nuggests of info include:

- names of function and method parameters
- class hierarchies
- source code of the implementation of a functions/class objects
- local variables out of a frame object

If you're just looking for "what attribute values does my object have?", then `dir()` and `__dict__` are probably sufficient. If you're really looking to dig into the current state of arbitrary objects (keeping in mind that in python almost everything is an object), then `inspect` is worthy of consideration.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using this for debugging, and you just want a recursive dump of everything, the accepted answer is unsatisfying because it requires that your classes have good `__str__` implementations already. If that's not the case, this works much better:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(YOUR_OBJECT, 
                 default=lambda obj: vars(obj),
                 indent=1))
```

Comment: this didn't work on python 3. Had to install pymongo and do it as per @Clark 's answer

Comment: as with many of the other answers here `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

Answer (score 11):

Try [ppretty](https://github.com/symonsoft/ppretty)

```
from ppretty import ppretty


class A(object):
    s = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self._p = 8

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return range(10)


print ppretty(A(), show_protected=True, show_static=True, show_properties=True)
```

Output:

```
__main__.A(_p = 8, foo = [0, 1, ..., 8, 9], s = 5)
```

Comment: little hint add depth=6 (or however far you need) as one of the parameters for it and the recursion details can go further :).  One of the things I like about how it prints lists is it shows the first 2 entires and last 2 entries so you know it's working

Answer (score 9):

A metaprogramming example [Dump object with magic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html):

```
$ cat dump.py
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    module, metaklass  = sys.argv[1:3]
    m = __import__(module, globals(), locals(), [metaklass])
    __metaclass__ = getattr(m, metaklass)

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 38
        self.lst = ['a','b','c']
        self.str = 'spam'
    dumps   = lambda self: repr(self)
    __str__ = lambda self: self.dumps()

data = Data()
print data
```

Without arguments:

```
$ python dump.py
```

```
<__main__.Data instance at 0x00A052D8>
```

With [Gnosis Utils](http://www.gnosis.cx/download/Gnosis_Utils.More/):

```
$ python dump.py gnosis.magic MetaXMLPickler
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PyObject SYSTEM "PyObjects.dtd">
<PyObject module="__main__" class="Data" id="11038416">
<attr name="lst" type="list" id="11196136" >
  <item type="string" value="a" />
  <item type="string" value="b" />
  <item type="string" value="c" />
</attr>
<attr name="num" type="numeric" value="38" />
<attr name="str" type="string" value="spam" />
</PyObject>
```

It is a bit outdated but still working.

Answer (score 9):

This prints out all the object contents recursively in json or yaml indented format:

```
import jsonpickle # pip install jsonpickle
import json
import yaml # pip install pyyaml

serialized = jsonpickle.encode(obj, max_depth=2) # max_depth is optional
print json.dumps(json.loads(serialized), indent=4)
print yaml.dump(yaml.load(serialized), indent=4)
```

Comment: If you just want to serialize to a string, you don't even need jsonpickle:
import yaml
print(yaml.dump(your_object))

Answer (score 7):

```
from pprint import pprint

def print_r(the_object):
    print ("CLASS: ", the_object.__class__.__name__, " (BASE CLASS: ", the_object.__class__.__bases__,")")
    pprint(vars(the_object))
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not something simple:

```
for key,value in obj.__dict__.iteritems():
    print key,value
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for key,value in obj.__dict__.iteritems(): print key,value`?

Comment: Nice, suited.
But fixed compile errors (maybe, other Python version)
for key, value in params.__dict__.items():
    print(key + " = " + str(value))

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see all the *values* in a complex data structure, then do something like:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(my_var)
```

Where *my_var* is your variable of interest. When I used `pprint(vars(my_var))` I got nothing, and other answers here didn't help or the method looked unnecessarily long. By the way, in my particular case, the code I was inspecting had a dictionary of dictionaries.

Worth pointing out that with some custom classes you may just end up with an unhelpful `<someobject.ExampleClass object at 0x7f739267f400>` kind of output. In that case, you might have to implement a `__str__` method, or try some of the other solutions.

I also found that in one instance where I got this `object` type of output, `vars()` showed me what I wanted. So a better solution to cover both cases would be to try both individually. But using `vars()` can sometimes throw an exception, for example, `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`.

I'd still like to find something simple that works in all scenarios, without third party libraries.

Answer (score 5):

This works no matter how your varibles are defined within a class, inside __init__ or outside.

```
your_obj = YourObj()
attrs_with_value = {attr: getattr(your_obj, attr) for attr in dir(your_obj)}
```

Comment: Addition to exclude all built-in vars (methods, functions etc) : `{attr: getattr(your_obj, attr) for attr in dir(your_obj) and "__" not in attr}`

Comment: @Vladimir I get a syntax error with your version ""attr" is not defined"

Answer (score 4):

I was needing to print DEBUG info in some logs and was unable to use pprint because it would break it.  Instead I did this and got virtually the same thing.

```
DO = DemoObject()

itemDir = DO.__dict__

for i in itemDir:
    print '{0}  :  {1}'.format(i, itemDir[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

To dump "myObject":

```
from bson import json_util
import json

print(json.dumps(myObject, default=json_util.default, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

I tried vars() and dir(); both failed for what I was looking for. vars() didn't work because the object didn't have __dict__ (exceptions.TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute). dir() wasn't what I was looking for: it's just a listing of field names, doesn't give the values or the object structure.

I think json.dumps() would work for most objects without the default=json_util.default, but I had a datetime field in the object so the standard json serializer failed. See [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python)

Comment: Okay yep had to install pymongo tho to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Just try [beeprint](https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint).

It will help you not only with printing object variables, but beautiful output as well, like this:

```
class(NormalClassNewStyle):
  dicts: {
  },
  lists: [],
  static_props: 1,
  tupl: (1, 2)
```

Comment: This module does not seemed to be maintained any more and have a number of open issues. Rather use [ppretty](https://github.com/symonsoft/ppretty)

Comment: beeprint is too verbose, can't figure out how to exclude e.g. properties starting with `_` etc. Not documented very well - or maintained.

Answer (score 3):

For everybody struggling with

- `vars()` not returning all attributes.
- `dir()` not returning the attributes' values.

The following code prints **all** attributes of `obj` with their values:

```
for attr in dir(obj):
        try:
            print("obj.{} = {}".format(attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
        except AttributeError:
            print("obj.{} = ?".format(attr))
```

Comment: get no errors, but not recursive so just get a lot of hex addresses

Answer (score 2):

[pprint](https://pymotw.com/3/pprint/index.html) contains a “pretty printer” for producing aesthetically pleasing representations of your data structures. The formatter produces representations of data structures that can be parsed correctly by the interpreter, and are also easy for a human to read. The output is kept on a single line, if possible, and indented when split across multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

While there are many good answers, here is a 1-liner that can give the attributes AS WELL AS values:

```
(str(vars(config)).split(",")[1:])
```

where 'config' is the object in question. I am listing this as a separate answer because I just wanted to simply print the relevant values of the object (excl the __main etc) without using loops or pretty print and didn't find a convenient answer.

Answer (score 1):

This project modifies pprint to show all object field values, it ignores he objects `__repr__` member function, it also recurses into nested objects. It works with python3, see https://github.com/MoserMichael/pprintex
You can install it via pip: `pip install printex`

Answer (score 1):

vars() seems to show the attributes of this object, but dir() seems to show attributes of parent class(es) as well. You don't usually need to see inherited attributes such as **str**, **doc**. **dict** etc.

```
In [1]: class Aaa():
...:     def __init__(self, name, age):
...:         self.name = name
...:         self.age = age
...:
In [2]: class Bbb(Aaa):
...:     def __init__(self, name, age, job):
...:         super().__init__(name, age)
...:         self.job = job
...:
In [3]: a = Aaa('Pullayya',42)

In [4]: b = Bbb('Yellayya',41,'Cop')

In [5]: vars(a)
Out[5]: {'name': 'Pullayya', 'age': 42}

In [6]: vars(b)
Out[6]: {'name': 'Yellayya', 'age': 41, 'job': 'Cop'}

In [7]: dir(a)
Out[7]:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 ...
 ...
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'age',
 'name']
```

Answer (score 1):

**`@dataclass` + `pprint` (recursive, indented, no external libs, Python 3.10)**

[`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is just amazing, and `pprint` from Python 3.10 learnt to print dataclasses with indentation, so if you can convert your code to `@dataclass` this is a very good approach:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pprint import pprint

@dataclass
class MyClass1:
    s: str
    n0: int
    n1: int
    n2: int
    n3: int
    n4: int
    n5: int
    n6: int
    n7: int
    n8: int
    n9: int

@dataclass
class MyClass2:
    s: str
    n0: int
    n1: int
    n2: int
    n3: int
    n4: int
    n5: int
    n6: int
    n7: int
    n8: int
    n9: int
    my_class_1: MyClass1

obj = MyClass2(s='a', n0=0, n1=1, n2=2, n3=3, n4=4, n5=5, n6=6, n7=7, n8=8, n9=9, my_class_1=MyClass1(s='a', n0=0, n1=1, n2=2, n3=3, n4=4, n5=5, n6=6, n7=7, n8=8, n9=9))
print(obj)
pprint(obj)
```

Output:

```
MyClass2(s='a', n0=0, n1=1, n2=2, n3=3, n4=4, n5=5, n6=6, n7=7, n8=8, n9=9, my_class_1=MyClass1(s='a', n0=0, n1=1, n2=2, n3=3, n4=4, n5=5, n6=6, n7=7, n8=8, n9=9))
MyClass2(s='a',
         n0=0,
         n1=1,
         n2=2,
         n3=3,
         n4=4,
         n5=5,
         n6=6,
         n7=7,
         n8=8,
         n9=9,
         my_class_1=MyClass1(s='a',
                             n0=0,
                             n1=1,
                             n2=2,
                             n3=3,
                             n4=4,
                             n5=5,
                             n6=6,
                             n7=7,
                             n8=8,
                             n9=9))
```

See also: [Pretty-print dataclasses prettier with line breaks and indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807878/pretty-print-dataclasses-prettier)

`@dataclass` also gives you other very good features for free:

- `__hash__` and `__eq__`: [Object of custom type as dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901815/object-of-custom-type-as-dictionary-key/75324312#75324312)
- `__slots__`: [Prevent creating new attributes outside __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603502/prevent-creating-new-attributes-outside-init/75411330#75411330)

**Vs other answers**

Let's create a comparable non `@dataclass` code

```
from pprint import pprint

class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, s, n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9):
        self.s = s
        self.n0 = n0
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self.n3 = n3
        self.n4 = n4
        self.n5 = n5
        self.n6 = n6
        self.n7 = n7
        self.n8 = n8
        self.n9 = n9

class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, s, n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, my_class_1):
        self.s = s
        self.n0 = n0
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self.n3 = n3
        self.n4 = n4
        self.n5 = n5
        self.n6 = n6
        self.n7 = n7
        self.n8 = n8
        self.n9 = n9
        self.n9 = n9
        self.my_class_1 = my_class_1

obj = MyClass2(s='a', n0=0, n1=1, n2=2, n3=3, n4=4, n5=5, n6=6, n7=7, n8=8, n9=9, my_class_1=MyClass1(s='a', n0=0, n1=1, n2=2, n3=3, n4=4, n5=5, n6=6, n7=7, n8=8, n9=9))
pprint(vars(obj))
```

`pprint(vars(obj))` output is non-recursive:

```
{'my_class_1': <__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x7fee21a9bf70>,
 'n0': 0,
 'n1': 1,
 'n2': 2,
 'n3': 3,
 'n4': 4,
 'n5': 5,
 'n6': 6,
 'n7': 7,
 'n8': 8,
 'n9': 9,
 's': 'a'}
```

Tested on Python 3.10.7, Ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Flask Debug Toolbar.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-DebugToolbar

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

app = Flask(__name__)

# the toolbar is only enabled in debug mode:
app.debug = True

# set a 'SECRET_KEY' to enable the Flask session cookies
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '<replace with a secret key>'

toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128615/1779027), it can be slightly modified to get only 'Attributes' of an object as below:

```
def getAttributes(obj):
    from pprint import pprint
    from inspect import getmembers
    from types import FunctionType
    
    def attributes(obj):
        disallowed_names = {
          name for name, value in getmembers(type(obj)) 
            if isinstance(value, FunctionType)}
        return {
          name for name in dir(obj) 
            if name[0] != '_' and name not in disallowed_names and hasattr(obj, name)}
    pprint(attributes(obj))
```

It is helpful when adding this function temporary and can be removed without many changes in existing source code

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested performance, but I believe this is the fastest method to enumerate just the properties / attributes / keys of any object in Python as a list.

```
# If core==False, ignore __k__ entries
def obj_props(obj, core=False) -> list:
    assert not obj is None, f"obj must not be null (None)"
    _props = []
    _use_dir=False
    def _add(p):
        if not core and p.find('__') == 0: return
        _props.append(p)
    if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'): 
        for p in obj.__dict__.keys(): _add(p)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__slots__'):
        for p in obj.__slots__: _add(p)
    elif hasattr(obj, 'keys'):
        try:
            for p in obj.keys(): _add(p)
        except Exception as ex:
            _props = []
            _use_dir = True
    else:
        _use_dir = True
    if _use_dir:
        # fall back to slow and steady
        for p in dir(obj):
            if not core and p.find('__') == 0: continue
            v = getattr(obj, p)
            v_t = type(v).__name__
            if v_t in ('function', 'method', 'builtin_function_or_method', 'method-wrapper'): continue
            _props.append(p)

    return _props
```

The above should work with regular python objects (with `__dict__`), objects using slots (`__slots__`) and even work with dictionary like objects.

Most other examples utilize `dir(obj)` which will enumerate all methods and properties of an object which will take a performance hit if you only need its properties.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to var_dump / print_r the browser state of Selenium, but some of its class properties are not always implemented / accessible (depending on the browser used), which causes exceptions in some cases. None of the solutions posted so far seemed to be able to work around that problem, so I was unable to dump all properties before things crashed. This is the only clean solution I could come up with:

```
import warnings

def dump(obj):
  for name in dir(obj):
    e = False
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
      warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
      try:
        v = getattr(obj, name)
      except:
        e = True
      warnings.simplefilter("default")
    if not e:
      print("obj.%s = %r" % (name, v))
    else:
      print("<inaccessible property obj.%s>" % name)
```

This also suppresses warnings (e.g. deprecations) upon accessing properties. Note that it is not recursive.

Answer (score -1):

I like working with python object built-in types [keys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys) or [values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.values).

For attributes regardless they are methods or variables:

```
o.keys()
```

For values of those attributes:

```
o.values()
```