# What is a Python equivalent of PHP's var_dump()?

Tags: php, python, debugging

When debugging in PHP, I frequently find it useful to simply stick a [var_dump()](http://php.net/var-dump) in my code to show me what a variable is, what its value is, and the same for anything that it contains.

What is a good Python equivalent for this?

Comment: I found this looking for the PHP equivalent for pythons repr. Thanks.

Comment: the duplicate question @hop mentions (and the highest voted answer) was much more useful for me

Comment: If you find yourself using this function a lot you may want to consider using a good remote debugger with breakpoints. It maybe hard to understand at first, but it will save you time in the future and once you know how to do it, you will never go back. I know eclipse has a good one and so does Komodo. http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/debugpython.html#Using_the_Python_Remote_Debugger

Comment: since this thread is closed, see this answer that uses jsonpickle serialization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35804583/1081043

Answer (score 331, accepted):

To display a value nicely, you can use the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module. The easiest way to dump all variables with it is to do

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(globals())
pprint(locals())
```

If you are running in CGI, a useful debugging feature is the [cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) module, which displays the value of local variables as part of the traceback.

Comment: what about showing the type of var? like Null/None, String, Object..

Comment: What about `pprint()` on _enumerate_ objects, _permutations_, etc.?

Comment: This was helpful. I am a Python noob but what seemed to help my case was using `.__dict__`, e.g. `pprint(object.__dict__)`.

Comment: ```object.__dict__``` outputs all the properties of the object

Comment: `var_dump` in PHP is not just about "displaying a value nicely" 

Answer (score 349):

I think the best equivalent to PHP's `var_dump($foo, $bar)` is combine [`print`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) with [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars):

```
print vars(foo),vars(bar)
```

Comment: Same here, only thing that worked as I expected (like var_dump)

Comment: Looks like for vars to work, the variable must have a dictionary info, otherwise you get "TypeError: vars() argument must have __ dict __ attribute".

Comment: This did it for me - but I like the pprint too. Here is a hybrid: `pprint.pprint(vars(foo))`.

Comment: -1, this works only for some types of variables, not all of them. Consider instead `pprint` or `repr`

Comment: This answer also works for python pdb debugging with the `pp` command. e.g. `pp vars(my_dict)`.  It should be marked as correct as php `var_dump()` outputs all the values in the data structure the same as py `vars()` does.

Comment: Note: For python3 you'll need to use parens  like `print( vars(foo) )`

Answer (score 75):

The closest thing to [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)'s `var_dump()` is `pprint()` with the `getmembers()` function in the built-in `inspect` module:

```
from inspect import getmembers
from pprint import pprint
pprint(getmembers(yourObj))
```

Comment: This way is much more better of good.

Answer (score 37):

I wrote a very light-weight alternative to PHP's var_dump for using in Python and made it open source later.

GitHub: https://github.com/sha256/python-var-dump

You can simply install it using [`pip`](http://pip.openplans.org/):

```sh
pip install var_dump
```

Usage example:

```
from var_dump import var_dump

var_dump(1, {"testkey1": "testval1", "testkey2": "testval2".encode("ascii")},
 ["testval"], "test", "test".encode("ascii"), set([1,2,3]))
```

prints

```
#0 int(1) 
#1 dict(2) 
    ['testkey1'] => str(8) "testval1"
    ['testkey2'] => object(bytes) (b'testval2')
#2 list(1)
    [0] => str(7) "testval"
#3 str(4) "test"
#4 object(bytes) (b'test')
#5 object(set) ({1, 2, 3})
```

Comment: Fails on sets - https://github.com/sha256/python-var-dump/issues/8

Comment: BEST of the best solution, EVER, this utility works so well and does unbelievable formatting of the output. I really strong recommend it!

Comment: @anatolytechtonik that was fixed at 2016-08 ^^

Answer (score 29):

PHP's [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) usually shows a serialized version of the object that can be exec()'d to re-create the object.    The closest thing to that in Python is [repr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr)

"For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval() [...]"

Comment: I think you're thinking of `var_export`.

Comment: yep, var_export in php and repr in python are somewhat related - that's if you want an official string representation of some object - you use repr(). In order to have non-official (read human-readable) you can always force conversion to string: str(object), which produces info similar to php's print_r() (used much more ofter for debugging than var_dump).

Comment: Please fix the answer, it's incorrect. As mentioned, either you're talking about var_export or describe var_dump() differently.

Answer (score 17):

So I have taken the answers from this question and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of) and came up below.  I suspect this is not pythonic enough for most people, but I really wanted something that let me get a deep representation of the values some unknown variable has.  I would appreciate any suggestions about how I can improve this or achieve the same behavior easier.

```
def dump(obj):
  '''return a printable representation of an object for debugging'''
  newobj=obj
  if '__dict__' in dir(obj):
    newobj=obj.__dict__
    if ' object at ' in str(obj) and not newobj.has_key('__type__'):
      newobj['__type__']=str(obj)
    for attr in newobj:
      newobj[attr]=dump(newobj[attr])
  return newobj
```

Here is the usage

```
class stdClass(object): pass
obj=stdClass()
obj.int=1
obj.tup=(1,2,3,4)
obj.dict={'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3, 'more':{'z':26,'y':25}}
obj.list=[1,2,3,'a','b','c',[1,2,3,4]]
obj.subObj=stdClass()
obj.subObj.value='foobar'

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dump(obj))
```

and the results.

```
{'__type__': '<__main__.stdClass object at 0x2b126000b890>',
 'dict': {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'more': {'y': 25, 'z': 26}},
 'int': 1,
 'list': [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', [1, 2, 3, 4]],
 'subObj': {'__type__': '<__main__.stdClass object at 0x2b126000b8d0>',
            'value': 'foobar'},
 'tup': (1, 2, 3, 4)}
```

Comment: +1, This is the only answer that actually has `var_dump`'s functionality when it encounters objects

Comment: +1 very useful, but it shows an error with "if '__dict__' in dir(obj):", I could correct using "if ' instance at ' in str(obj) and obj.__dict__:"

Comment: this function only take 1 argument, php's var_dump() take *args

Answer (score 9):

Old topic, but worth a try.

Here is a simple and efficient `var_dump` function:

```
def var_dump(var, prefix=''):
    """
    You know you're a php developer when the first thing you ask for
    when learning a new language is 'Where's var_dump?????'
    """
    my_type = '[' + var.__class__.__name__ + '(' + str(len(var)) + ')]:'
    print(prefix, my_type, sep='')
    prefix += '    '
    for i in var:
        if type(i) in (list, tuple, dict, set):
            var_dump(i, prefix)
        else:
            if isinstance(var, dict):
                print(prefix, i, ': (', var[i].__class__.__name__, ') ', var[i], sep='')
            else:
                print(prefix, '(', i.__class__.__name__, ') ', i, sep='')
```

Sample output:

```
>>> var_dump(zen)

[list(9)]:
    (str) hello
    (int) 3
    (int) 43
    (int) 2
    (str) goodbye
    [list(3)]:
        (str) hey
        (str) oh
        [tuple(3)]:
            (str) jij
            (str) llll
            (str) iojfi
    (str) call
    (str) me
    [list(7)]:
        (str) coucou
        [dict(2)]:
            oKey: (str) oValue
            key: (str) value
        (str) this
        [list(4)]:
            (str) a
            (str) new
            (str) nested
            (str) list
```

Comment: ```if type(i) in (list, tuple, dict, set):``` does not seem to work. When passing an object: ```TypeError: object of type 'TestPacketDecode' has no len()```

Answer (score 2):

`print`

For your own classes, just def a `__str__` method

Answer (score 2):

I don't have PHP experience, but I have an understanding of the Python standard library.

For your purposes, Python has several methods:

[logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module;

Object serialization module which is called [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). You may write your own wrapper of the pickle module.

If your using `var_dump` for testing, Python has its own [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) and [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) modules. It's very simple and fast for design.

Answer (score 1):

I use self-written Printer class, but dir() is also good for outputting the instance fields/values.

```
class Printer:

       def __init__ (self, PrintableClass):
           for name in dir(PrintableClass):
               value = getattr(PrintableClass,name)
               if  '_' not in str(name).join(str(value)):
                    print '  .%s: %r' % (name, value)
```

The sample of usage:

```
Printer(MyClass)
```

Comment: if '_' not in str(name).join(str(value)): ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax