# global() function call in legacy Python code

Tags: python

I'm tracing a legacy project, and see the source code is doing this:

```
globals()['my-str']
```

I know we use `global` keyword when we want to change the value for the global variable in a local scope.

But what does `global()` do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958904/why-is-globals-a-function-in-python

Comment: Notice it says `globals`, not `global`. [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to look things up before asking questions, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+globals+function). There is nothing at all "legacy" about this built-in function, which is still provided and not deprecated in current versions of Python. It's just that it solves a problem that is usually better sidestepped entirely.

Comment: You've inherited bad code

Answer (score -1):

You can use the python interperter or pydoc to help you answer questions about keywords and builtins

```bash
$> pydoc globals
```

output:

```
Help on built-in function globals in module __builtin__:

globals(...)
    globals() -> dictionary
    
    Return the dictionary containing the current scope's global variables.
(END)
```

edit: `globals` is not a keyword, it is a builtin

Comment: Note the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the references therein both to "questions that have been asked (and answered) many times before", and to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (which explicitly defines questions caused by a typographic error -- in this case, failing to distinguish `global` vs `globals` -- as off-topic).

Comment: To be clear, `globals` isn't a keyword.

Comment: https://youtu.be/N7v0yvdkIHg