# Evaluating math expressions in a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, equation-solving, mathematical-expressions

I've a bunch of equations that are loaded from a [JSON file](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/tst.json) and I'd like to evaluate these expressions. These expressions have some constants and values of the constants (`K1`, `K2`, ...) are also saved in the json file. The values corresponding to the variables (`var1`, `var2` ...) present in the expressions are defined in a dictionary `vars`. I want to plugin the values of the constants and the variables in the expressions and compute the numerical values.

```
import json
vars = {"var1": 1, "var2": 2, "var3": 3, "var4": 4, "var5": 5, "var6": 5}
with open("tst.json", 'r') as f:
     r = json.load(f)
     print(r)
```

json content:

```
{
  "EQ1": {
    "parameters": {
      "EQ1_coeff1": {
        "value": 1.0e-06
      },
      "P2": {
        "value": 3.0
      },
      "P3": {
        "value": 3.0
      }
    },
    "expression": "(EQ1_coeff1 * ((1 dimensionless)/(1 dimensionless)) / (1 dimensionless))*(var1^P3/(var1^P3 + P2^P3) )"
  },
  "EQ2": {
    "parameters": {
      "EQ2_coeff2": {
        "value": 5253
      },
      "K2": {
        "value": 3
      },
      "K5": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "K3": {
        "value": 525
      },
      "K4": {
        "value": 3
      },
      "K6": {
        "value": 2
      },
      "K7": {
        "value": 0.01
      }
    },
    "expression": "(EQ2_coeff2 *((var2*var3)/(K1*K2))* ((1 dimensionless - ((var3*var4)/(var2))/K6) / ((1 dimensionless + var1/K1)*(1 dimensionless + var2)+ 1 dimensionless)))*(1 dimensionless/(1 dimensionless + var5/K7))"
  }
}
```

I'd like to ask for suggestions on how these expressions (stored in `expression`) can be computed.

Side note:

`1 dimensionless` is nothing but 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will simply update the `globals()` with the `dict` and then use `eval`, as done below:

```
import json
vars = {"var1": 1, "var2": 2, "var3": 3, "var4": 4, "var5": 5, "var6": 5}
r = {
  "EQ1": {
    "parameters": {
      "EQ1_coeff1": {
        "value": 1.0e-06
      },
      "P2": {
        "value": 3.0
      },
      "P3": {
        "value": 3.0
      }
    },
    "expression": "(EQ1_coeff1 * ((1 dimensionless)/(1 dimensionless)) / (1 dimensionless))*(var1^P3/(var1^P3 + P2^P3) )"
  },
  "EQ2": {
    "parameters": {
      "EQ2_coeff2": {
        "value": 5253
      },
      "K2": {
        "value": 3
      },
      "K5": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "K3": {
        "value": 525
      },
      "K4": {
        "value": 3
      },
      "K6": {
        "value": 2
      },
      "K7": {
        "value": 0.01
      }
    },
    "expression": "(EQ2_coeff2 *((var2*var3)/(K1*K2))* ((1 dimensionless - ((var3*var4)/(var2))/K6) / ((1 dimensionless + var1/K1)*(1 dimensionless + var2)+ 1 dimensionless)))*(1 dimensionless/(1 dimensionless + var5/K7))"
  }
}

globals().update( **{k:v['value'] for k,v in r["EQ1"]["parameters"].items()})
globals().update( **{k:v['value'] for k,v in r["EQ2"]["parameters"].items()})
globals().update(**vars)

eval(r['EQ1']['expression'].replace("dimensionless", "").replace("^", "**"))
```

This gives: `3.571428571428571e-08`

For `EQ2`  you do not have variable `K1` defined. This is more of a hack, I am not aware of a more elegant way though. Also keep in mind `eval` is a not very safe function.

Comment: thanks a lot, it helps! Could you please let me know in what form of expression evaluations `Also keep in mind eval is a not very safe function` this is not safe.

Comment: M happy to help :). `eval` can cause trouble if you get the string from an untrusted  source. Some malicious string when executed can do serious damage.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Also, could you please explain a bit on how global works. Thank you ver much!

Comment: globals() returns a dictionary which tell all the variables available in the global scope. This answer is very instructive https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694065/4551984