# Python. Get structure from a data.frame

Tags: python, r, pandas

In [r](/questions/tagged/r), with the `str()` function you can see structure from an object like this:

```
> str(mari)
'data.frame':   25834 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Xcoor: num  0.0457 0.0469 0.0481 0.0495 0.0519 ...
 $ Ycoor: num  0.107 0.107 0.107 0.108 0.108 ...
 $ Zcoor: num  -0.701 -0.701 -0.701 -0.703 -0.703 ...
 $ RC   : int  120 124 124 125 124 122 120 120 120 120 ...
 $ GC   : int  121 117 117 117 118 119 120 120 120 120 ...
 $ BC   : int  127 135 144 135 126 127 125 125 124 137 ...
```

Is there a similar function like this one?

Comment: the python library `pandas` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for an equivalent of `R`s `data.frame`, you will want to look into `pandas`.

The `pandas.DataFrame` might be what you are looking for.

The get an idea of what is in a `DataFrame` you could use the `.describe` or `.head` methods.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

print(data.head())
print(data.describe())
print(data.columns)
```

Or, which might be a little to verbose, just:

```
print(data)
```

Answer (score 26):

I realize this is an old question, but wanted to provide clarification for anyone else that comes across this question in the future like I did.

As MaxNoe said, `pandas` is what is needed and the `pandas.DataFrame.info` method is the equivalent to the `str()` function in R.

Using the same example as MaxNoe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})
>>> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    5 non-null int64
b    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

The documentation can be found here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html.

Answer (score 7):

The functions below may help you find the data types of a DF.

```
DF.info


DF.dtypes

OP:
ltv                                    float64
branch_id                                int64
supplier_id                              int64
manufacturer_id                          int64
Current_pincode_ID                       int64
Date.of.Birth                           object
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer provides the most similar information as str() in R.

Answer (score 4):

### Quick Answer:

`str(your-dataframe)` equivalent in [python](/questions/tagged/python) is `your-dataframe.dtypes`

In your case will be:

```py
mari.dtypes
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, all of the suggestions I see as of now (January 2024) will only help if you have a python *DataFrame*, or are working in `pandas`. If you have a *list* or something entirely different, these will not work;
however, `type()`
is a very basic python equivalent of R's `str()`.

So, to return the structure of your object `mari`,

```
    print(type(mari))
```

will display that value.

[Here is a page with an answer that lists python's "strong set of introspection features"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006169/how-do-i-look-inside-a-python-object).