# Attribute error in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I am doing the django tutorial so I am literally cutting and pasting code. I keep getting this error on step 1

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.conf.urls import include

 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 ]
```

I am getting this error

```
 */django/theSite/polls/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'
```

edit: 
my views module is this

```
 from django.shortcuts import render

 # Create your views here.
 from django.http import HttpResponse


 def index(request):
     return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

I cant see what I missed do you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Clearly the `views` module doesn't define an `index` name.

Comment: I added my views.py in I think it has an index

Comment: Show your views.py file: there's like an error there. Also double check that both files are in the same (polls/) subdirectory.

Comment: Whoops, thanks guys here is my views.py and they are both in the /polls directory

Comment: There's still an `__init__.py` in that directory as well?

Comment: yes, I never touched it and generated it with manage.py per the instructions

Comment: Clean up any `views.pyc` that might be lying around, just to be safe.  And your relevant `views.py` is in the same directory as the `urls.py`, right?

Comment: they are both under the /polls directory

I deleted the .pyc files no change still getting the error

Comment: I'd do an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` after you `import views` and try to figure out what you're actually importing.  You can [introspect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006169/how-do-i-look-inside-a-python-object) the module to see what it exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was indeed there had to be something wrong with my views. Deleting the django project and rebuilding the entire tutorial from scratch remedied the issue.