# speech recognition not recognising on internal mic

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I was making my personal assistant speech_recognition is working properly with headphones but without headphones on internal mic it is not recognising the voice.

Code:

```py
with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        speak("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1  
        audio = r.listen(source)
```

OS: Ventura 13.4 (M1)

Comment: Can you print the contents of the object `sr.Microphone()` please?

Comment: @KathyReid <speech_recognition.Microphone object at 0x108b3dd10>

Comment: The _contents_ of the object, please

Comment: @KathyReid didn't understand that can you please Clear it for me

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006169/how-do-i-look-inside-a-python-object for information on how to get the _attributes_ of a Python object. This is called "introspection".

Comment: ok what should I provide you? type or dir?

Comment: Which one shows the _contents_ of the object?

Comment: I think dir()
``
['CHUNK', 'MicrophoneStream', 'SAMPLE_RATE', 'SAMPLE_WIDTH', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'audio', 'device_index', 'format', 'get_pyaudio', 'list_microphone_names', 'list_working_microphones', 'pyaudio_module', 'stream']
``

Comment: @KathyReid Also .__dict__
{'pyaudio_module': <module 'pyaudio' from '/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/personal assistant/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py'>, 'device_index': 1, 'format': 8, 'SAMPLE_WIDTH': 2, 'SAMPLE_RATE': 48000, 'CHUNK': 1024, 'audio': None, 'stream': None}

Comment: Thanks @ansh - now, how do the values in the `__dict__` call compare when you have your headphones as the audio source? What is the same or different?

Comment: with headphones: {'pyaudio_module': <module 'pyaudio' from '/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/personal assistant/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py'>, 'device_index': None, 'format': 8, 'SAMPLE_WIDTH': 2, 'SAMPLE_RATE': 48000, 'CHUNK': 1024, 'audio': None, 'stream': None}
\n
without: 
{'pyaudio_module': <module 'pyaudio' from '/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/personal assistant/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py'>, 'device_index': None, 'format': 8, 'SAMPLE_WIDTH': 2, 'SAMPLE_RATE': 96000, 'CHUNK': 1024, 'audio': None, 'stream': None}

Comment: @KathyReid check above comment.

Comment: So, the only difference I see between the headphones and the internal microphone is the sample rate: the headphones are sampling at 48kHz and the internal mic is sampling at 96kHz. Is there a way to change the sample rate of  your internal microphone to be 48kHz? Is the code expecting a particular frequency of the audio sample (like 48kHz)?

Also, what is the output of the `audio` variable? What is the `type` of that variable?

Comment: yes I think module allows me to change the frequency

Comment: OK changing sample rate worked for me thanks @KathyReid

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, good luck with your project! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to KathyReid for helping me in comments.

Actually it was really easy it worked by just change sample rate from 96KHz to 48KHz

Here is a code edit:

```py
with sr.Microphone(sample_rate=48000) as source:
        print("Listening...")
        speak("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1  
        audio = r.listen(source)
```