# How can I recursively print the contents of a variable, including both the data and object attributes?

Tags: python, debugging, recursion, var-dump

`str()` and `repr()` can be used to print the contents of a variable in python. But the contents of a variable may be quite complex. The `pprint` library, reported as the [php `var_dump()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034530/php-print-all-properties-of-an-object) equivalent, works nicely for displaying just data in an easy to read format: [What is a Python equivalent of PHP's var_dump()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383944/what-is-a-python-equivalent-of-phps-var-dump), [Is there a function in Python to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of)

However if there are objects in the data (*[edit]* that haven't implemented `__str__` or `__repr__`), `str()`, `repr()` and `pprint` just gives their names. I'd like a method that can recursively walk through objects' attributes too, properly giving the entire representation of a variable.

Certain functions such as builtins shouldn't be printed as it's not useful. The method should also be able to handle issues such as `getattr` throwing exceptions. Perhaps custom iterables could also be handled the same way as lists.

---

I've given it a shot below. Not that it doesn't work, but I'm sure there are edge cases not accounted for and probably some missing information from the output (e.g. distinguish tuples/lists). What I mean to say is, please share alternatives :)

Comment: Why don't you implement `__repr__` and/or `__str__` for the objects you want to print out?

Comment: Heads up, you should probably put your attempt into the question, not submit it as an answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if I knew my way around the objects I wouldn't need to print them out. The idea of this function is to help me see the structure of other peoples data at runtime. In my specific case, django apps.

Comment: Subclass [`PrettyPrinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter) overriding `pformat()`, `isreadable(object)` and `isrecursive(object)`

Comment: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg (I believe you meant "*how about using a debugger such as...*" ;) ) I think a debugger is too heavy weight for my purposes. With a complete list of objects in-browser I can quickly see which variables I have access to in my django templates and don't have to mess with the webserver.

Answer (score 12):

This prints out all the object contents recursively in json or yaml (take your pick) indented format:

```
import jsonpickle # pip install jsonpickle
import json
import yaml # pip install pyyaml

serialized = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
print json.dumps(json.loads(serialized), indent=4)
print yaml.dump(yaml.load(serialized), indent=4)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's my answer. This works pretty well for my purposes, but again, I'm sure there are more robust ways to do this. If you have a better way, please share it :)

```
import types
def var_dump(obj, depth=4, l=""):
    #fall back to repr
    if depth<0: return repr(obj)
    #expand/recurse dict
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        name = ""
        objdict = obj
    else:
        #if basic type, or list thereof, just print
        canprint=lambda o:isinstance(o, (int, float, str, unicode, bool, types.NoneType, types.LambdaType))
        try:
            if canprint(obj) or sum(not canprint(o) for o in obj) == 0: return repr(obj)
        except TypeError, e:
            pass
        #try to iterate as if obj were a list
        try:
            return "[\n" + "\n".join(l + var_dump(k, depth=depth-1, l=l+"  ") + "," for k in obj) + "\n" + l + "]"
        except TypeError, e:
            #else, expand/recurse object attribs
            name = (hasattr(obj, '__class__') and obj.__class__.__name__ or type(obj).__name__)
            objdict = {}
            for a in dir(obj):
                if a[:2] != "__" and (not hasattr(obj, a) or not hasattr(getattr(obj, a), '__call__')):
                    try: objdict[a] = getattr(obj, a)
                    except Exception, e: objdict[a] = str(e)
    return name + "{\n" + "\n".join(l + repr(k) + ": " + var_dump(v, depth=depth-1, l=l+"  ") + "," for k, v in objdict.iteritems()) + "\n" + l + "}"
```

Example output:

```
class B(object):
    mystatic = [1,2,3]  

class A:
    mystatic = "hello"
    def __init__(self):
        self.mymember1 = B()
        self.mymember2 = B(), 123.4, "world"
    def myfunc(self):
        print "hi"

var = {"foo": A(), "bar": B()}

...

>>> print var_dump(var)
{
'foo': A{
  'mystatic': 'hello',
  'mymember1': B{
    'mystatic': [1, 2, 3],
    },
  'mymember2': [
    B{
      'mystatic': [1, 2, 3],
      },
    123.4,
    'world',
    ],
  },
'bar': B{
  'mystatic': [1, 2, 3],
  },
}
```

I originally wrote this because django's debug toolbar used `pprint` and was only showing first level data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive pretty-printer I created a while ago to inspect data structures of my projects. It's able to handle arbitrary objects, provides useful output for common data types and allows some customization via arguments. Commented out lines represent alternatives one might want to use. Code is also available as [Gist](https://gist.github.com/fonic/dfcaa350d5fb57835cf6c1689d251912):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Recursively generate pretty print of arbitrary objects
def generate_pprint(obj, level_indent="  ", max_depth=None, verbose_output=True,
                    justify_output=True, prevent_loops=True, prevent_revisit=False,
                    explore_objects=True, excluded_ids=[], visited_ids=[],
                    path_ids=[], current_depth=0):
    """Recursively generates pretty print of arbitrary objects.

    Recursively generates pretty print of contents of arbitrary objects. Contents
    are represented as lines containing key-value pairs. Recursion may be affected
    by various parameters (see below).

    Arguments:
        max_depth:       Maximum allowed depth of recursion. If depth is exceeded,
                         recursion is stopped.
        verbose_output:  Produce verbose output. Adds some additional details for
                         certain data types
        justify_output:  Justify output. Produces output in block-like appearance
                         with equal spacing between keys and values.
        prevent_loops:   Detect and prevent recursion loops by keeping track of
                         already visited objects within current recursion path.
        prevent_revisit: Detect and prevent revisiting of already visited objects.
                         While 'prevent_loops' prevents revisiting objects only
                         within one single recursion path, this prevents revisiting
                         objects globally across all recursion paths.
        explore_objects: Explore (i.e. recurse into) arbitrary objects. If enabled,
                         arbitrary objects not matching base types are explored.
                         If disabled, only certain types of objects are explored
                         (tuple, list, dict, set/frozenset). Note that this does
                         not affect the initially provided object (which is always
                         explored).
        excluded_ids:    List of object IDs to exclude from exploration (i.e. re-
                         cursion). Recursion is stopped if object with matching
                         ID is encountered.
        visited_ids,     Internal variables used to control recursion flow, loop
        path_ids,        detection and revisit detection. Never provide or modify
        current_depth:   these!

    Returns:
        Generated pretty print output as list of lines (strings).

    Raises:
        TypeError:       Object or value has unsupported type (should never occur)
        AssertionError:  Assertion failed, most likely exposing a bug (should never
                         occur)
    """

    output = []
    indent = level_indent * current_depth

    # Check if object has already been visited within current recursion path.
    # If so, we encoutered a loop and thus need to break off recursion. If
    # not, continue and add object to list of visited objects within current
    # recursion path
    if (prevent_loops == True):
        if (id(obj) in path_ids):
            output.append(indent + "<recursion loop detected>")
            return output
        path_ids.append(id(obj))

    # Check if object has already been visited. If so, we're not going to visit
    # it again and break off recursion. If not, continue and add current object
    # to list of visited objects
    if (prevent_revisit == True):
        if (id(obj) in visited_ids):
            output.append(indent + "<item already visited>")
            return output
        visited_ids.append(id(obj))

    # Check if maximum allowed depth of recursion has been exceeded. If so, break
    # off recursion
    if (max_depth != None and current_depth > max_depth):
        output.append(indent + "<recursion limit reached>")
        return output

    # Check if object is supposed to be excluded. If so, break of recursion
    if (id(obj) in excluded_ids):
        output.append(indent + "<item is excluded>")
        return output

    # Determine keys and associated values
    if (isinstance(obj, dict)):
        keys = obj.keys()
        values = obj
    elif (isinstance(obj, tuple) or isinstance(obj, list)):
        keys = range(0, len(obj))
        values = obj
    elif (isinstance(obj, set) or isinstance(obj, frozenset)):
        keys = range(0, len(obj))
        values = [ item for item in obj ]
    elif (isinstance(obj, object)):
        keys = [ item for item in dir(obj) if (not item.startswith("_")) ]
        values = { key: getattr(obj, key) for key in keys }
    else: # should never occur as everything in Python is an 'object' and should be caught above, but better be safe than sorry
        raise TypeError("unsupported object type: '%s'" % type(obj))

    # Define key string templates. If output is to be justified, determine maximum
    # length of key string and adjust templates accordingly
    kstmp1 = kstmp2 = "%s"
    if (justify_output == True):
        maxlen = 0
        for key in keys:
            klen = len(str(key))
            if (klen > maxlen):
                maxlen = klen
        kstmp1 = "%-" + str(maxlen+3) + "s" # maxlen+3: surrounding single quotes + trailing colon
        kstmp2 = "%-" + str(maxlen+1) + "s" # maxlen+1: trailing colon

    # Process keys and associated values
    for key in keys:
        value = values[key]

        # Generate key string
        keystr = kstmp1 % ("'" + str(key) + "':") if (isinstance(obj, dict) and isinstance(key, str)) else kstmp2 % (str(key) + ":")

        # Generate value string
        valstr = ""
        exp_obj = False
        if (isinstance(value, dict)):
            valstr = "<dict, %d items, class '%s'>" % (len(value), type(value).__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<dict, %d items>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, tuple)):
            valstr = "<tuple, %d items, class '%s'>" % (len(value), type(value).__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<tuple, %d items>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, list)):
            valstr = "<list, %d items, class '%s'>" % (len(value), type(value).__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<list, %d items>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, set)): # set and frozenset are distinct
            valstr = "<set, %d items, class '%s'>" % (len(value), type(value).__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<set, %d items>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, frozenset)): # set and frozenset are distinct
            valstr = "<frozenset, %d items, class '%s'>" % (len(value), type(value).__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<frozenset, %d items>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, range)):
            valstr = "<range, start %d, stop %d, step %d>" % (value.start, value.stop, value.step) if (verbose_output == True) else "<range(%d,%d,%d)>" % (value.start, value.stop, value.step)
        elif (isinstance(value, bytes)):
            valstr = "<bytes, %d bytes>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, bytearray)):
            valstr = "<bytearray, %d bytes>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, memoryview)):
            valstr = "<memoryview, %d bytes, object %s>" % (len(value), type(value.obj).__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<memoryview, %d bytes>" % len(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, bool)): # needs to be above int as 'bool' also registers as 'int'
            valstr = "%s" % value
        elif (isinstance(value, int)):
            valstr = "%d (0x%x)" % (value, value)
        elif (isinstance(value, float)):
            valstr = "%s" % str(value) # str(value) provides best representation; alternatives: '%e|%E|%f|%F|%g|%G' % value
        elif (isinstance(value, complex)):
            valstr = "%s" % str(value)
        elif (isinstance(value, str)):
            #valstr = "%s" % repr(value) # using repr(value) to encode escape sequences (e.g. '\n' instead of actual newline); repr() adds surrounding quotes for strings (style based on contents)
            #valstr = "%r" % value # alternative, seems to be the same as repr(value)
            valstr = "'%s'" % repr(value)[1:-1] # this seems to be the only way to always get a single-quoted string
        elif (value == None):
            valstr = "None"
        elif isinstance(value, type): # checks if object is 'class' (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123520/1976617); needs to be above 'callable' as 'class' also registers as 'callable'
            #valstr = "<class '%s'>" % type(value).__name__ if (verbose_output == True) else "<class>"
            valstr = "<class '%s.%s'>" % (value.__module__, value.__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<class>"
        elif (callable(value)): # catches everything callable, i.e. functions, methods, classes (due to constructor), etc.
            #valstr = "<callable, %s>" % repr(value)[1:-1] if (verbose_output == True) else "<callable>"
            #valstr = "<callable, class '%s'>" % type(value).__name__ if (verbose_output == True) else "<callable>"
            valstr = "<callable, class '%s.%s'>" % (value.__class__.__module__, value.__class__.__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<callable>"
        elif (isinstance(value, object)): # this has to be last in line as *everything* above also registers as 'object'
            #valstr = "<object, class '%s'>" % type(value).__name__ if (verbose_output == True) else "<object>"
            valstr = "<object, class '%s.%s'>" % (value.__class__.__module__, value.__class__.__name__) if (verbose_output == True) else "<object>"
            if (explore_objects == True):
                exp_obj = True # this ensures we only explore objects that do not represent a base type (i.e. everything listed above)
        else: # should never occur as everything in Python is an 'object' and should be caught above, but better be safe than sorry
            #valstr = "'%s'" % str(value) if (verbose_output == True) else str(value)
            raise TypeError("unsupported value type: '%s'" % type(value))

        # Generate key-value line from key/value strings and add to output
        output.append(indent + keystr + " " + valstr)

        # Explore value object recursively if it meets certain criteria
        if (isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, tuple) or isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, set) or
            isinstance(value, frozenset) or (isinstance(value, object) and exp_obj == True)):
            # These may be used to prevent recursion beforehand, i.e. before calling this
            # function again, as an alternative to checks at beginning of function. Leaving
            # this here for future reference
            #if (prevent_loops == True and id(value) in path_ids):
            #    #output[-1] += " <recursion loop detected>"
            #    output[-1] += " <recursion loop>"
            #    continue
            #if (prevent_revisit == True and id(value) in visited_ids):
            #    #output[-1] += " <item already visited>"
            #    output[-1] += " <already visited>"
            #    continue
            #if (max_depth != None and current_depth+1 > max_depth):
            #    #output[-1] += " <recusion limit reached>"
            #    output[-1] += " <recursion limit>"
            #    continue
            #if (id(value) in excluded_ids):
            #    #output[-1] += " <item is excluded>"
            #    output[-1] += " <item excluded>"
            #    continue
            output += generate_pprint(value, level_indent=level_indent, max_depth=max_depth, verbose_output=verbose_output,
                                      justify_output=justify_output, prevent_loops=prevent_loops, prevent_revisit=prevent_revisit,
                                      explore_objects=explore_objects, excluded_ids=excluded_ids, visited_ids=visited_ids,
                                      path_ids=path_ids, current_depth=current_depth + 1)

    # Remove object from list of visited objects within current recursion path
    # (part of recursion loop detection; this 'rolls back' the laid out path)
    if (prevent_loops == True):
        assert len(path_ids) > 0 and path_ids[-1] == id(obj), "last item in list of path objects not existing or not matching object"
        path_ids.pop()

    # Return generated output
    return output

# Convenience wrapper for generate_pprint()
def print_pprint(*args, **kwargs):
    output = generate_pprint(*args, **kwargs)
    for line in output:
        print(line)

# Demonstration (executed if run directly)
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    import sys
    print_pprint(sys)
```