# How to list all class properties

Tags: python, serialization, properties

I have class SomeClass with properties. For example `id` and `name`:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__id = None
        self.__name = None

    def get_id(self):
        return self.__id

    def set_id(self, value):
        self.__id = value

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, value):
        self.__name = value

    id = property(get_id, set_id)
    name = property(get_name, set_name)
```

What is the easiest way to list properties? I need this for serialization.

Comment: Related: [python - Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
property_names=[p for p in dir(SomeClass) if isinstance(getattr(SomeClass,p),property)]
```

Comment: Alas, this will miss inherited properties...!

Comment: I have tried this and it works fine for inherited classes also.

Answer (score 42):

```
import inspect

def isprop(v):
  return isinstance(v, property)

propnames = [name for (name, value) in inspect.getmembers(SomeClass, isprop)]
```

[`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) gets inherited members as well (and selects members by a predicate, here we coded `isprop` because it's not among the many predefined ones in module `inspect`; you could also use a `lambda`, of course, if you prefer).

Comment: FYI you *must* call `getmembers` on a class, not an instance, if you want to get properties. Functions, on the other hand, can be obtained from either.