# Iterate through class members in order of their declaration

Tags: python

I got this problem writing a little GUI lib that maps classes to simple table views. Every class member of a certain type = column, and order of columns is important. But...

```
class Person(object):

    name = None
    date_of_birth = None
    nationality = None
    gender = None
    address = None
    comment = None


for member in Person.__dict__.iteritems():
    if not member[1]:
        print member[0]
```

output:

```
comment
date_of_birth
name
address
gender
nationality
...
```

ugh, the oder got all mixed up...desired output:

```
name
date_of_birth
nationality
gender
address
comment
```

Is there a way to do it without maintaining additional `OrderedDict()` of columns?

Comment: A dict is by definition unordered, so you cannot rely on any ordering of class attributes and you'll have to maintain ordering elsewhere.

Comment: Just a thought, slightly nasty but would it be possible to swap out `__dict__` for an ordered dict? Might still be better to maintain the order elsewhere, but might be cool to see

Comment: @MartijnPieters not true, you can do that via a metaclass. In fact that use-case is explicitly mentioned in both the Python 3.x metaclass PEP (3115) and the OrderedDict PEP (372).

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Which shows that I am not using P3 all that often just yet.. thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible in Python3, through the use of [PEP3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) which allows you to override the dict type in the metaclass while the class is being constructed (eg. to use an OrderedDict which tracks the insertion order).  Here's an implementation of this approach:

```
class OrderedMeta(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases): 
        return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        c = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, clsdict)
        c._orderedKeys = clsdict.keys()
        return c

class Person(metaclass=OrderedMeta):
    name = None
    date_of_birth = None
    nationality = None
    gender = None
    address = None
    comment = None

for member in Person._orderedKeys:
    if not getattr(Person, member):
        print(member)
```

In Python2, it's a lot more tricky.  It would be achievable with something fairly hacky like introspecting the source, and working out the definition order from the AST, but that's probably a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It looks interesting, thanks! But I'm using Python 2 and I'm not sure this case justifies a switch to Py3

Comment: Even if I can't use this solution myself, it looks to me like a closest answer to my question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is an aggregate of variables, perhaps you should use a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead. It also maintains the order of the fields (as it's a tuple).

```
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', ('name',
                               'data_of_birth',
                               'nationality',
                               'gender',
                               'address',
                               'comment'))
print Person._fields
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but while it gets the job done in the end, the whole idea was to keep declaration clean and simple. This solution does not look very readable to me, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's not an answer per se but a workaround that only works in the context of original question ("Every class member [which is an instance] of a **certain type** = column, and order of columns is important"). The solution is to introduce a class variable `_count` into the `CertainType` class, and increment it at every instantiation. After that all class members of the CertainType are packed into a list which is sorted using `key=attrgetter('_count')`

P.S. Omitting that "which is an instance" part was a mistake on my part and it has limited range of solutions considerably. Sorry for that.