# Is it possible to iterate through class trait in order of declaration using Enthought traits?

Tags: python, enthought

We use Enthought Traits to declare some python classes that are use to create database schema and the UI to add records. So we have code to iterate through the class traits and do some actions. One common issue is that the order of declaration is usually significant or very helpful to understand the schema and the UI but this order is lost in `class_traits` (because it's a python dict).

Is there a way to automatically keep the declaration order in `class_traits`? Maybe by overriding some methods in `HasTraits`?

We use python 2 right now (we are in the process of moving to python 3 but it will take time).

**EDIT**: Before posting, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296010/iterate-through-class-members-in-order-of-their-declaration) which suggested a trick similar to what Robert Kern suggested but without snippet. I was expecting that Traits would provide some help there. Robert's answer is useful anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily in Python 2. Python 2 simply doesn't preserve that information.

If you are running with `.py` sources available, then it is possible to reparse the class definition from that file and reconstruct the order that way. If you aren't, then I suppose you could try to parse the bytecode, but you're on your own there.

```
import ast
import inspect


def ordered_class_traits(cls):
    source = inspect.getsource(cls)
    mod_ast = ast.parse(source)
    class_trait_names = cls.class_trait_names()
    class_ast = mod_ast.body[0]
    for node in class_ast.body:
        # This probably doesn't capture every possible trait declaration
        # out there, but it does the job for most of them.
        if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
            target = node.targets[0]
            if isinstance(target, ast.Name):
                if target.id in class_trait_names:
                    yield target.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I will advise on the possibility to include it.