# Getting AWS AMI properties

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, ec2-ami

I have a list of AMIs, which I got by creating a boto connection:

```
conn_eu = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
images = conn_eu.get_all_images(owners=['me'])
```

I want to be able to see the properties of these AMIs. Properties such as their descriptions, names and their image ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at [image.py](https://code.google.com/p/boto/source/browse/trunk/boto/ec2/image.py?r=978), I realised I can just do:
image.id to get image id
and image.description to get image description

Answer (score 2):

Here are all of the properties of the **boto.ec2.image.Image** object per [Print all properties of a Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969806/print-all-properties-of-a-python-class):

```
from boto.ec2 import connect_to_region
ec2_connection = connect_to_region("us-west-2",
          aws_access_key_id="...",
          aws_secret_access_key="...")
images = ec2_connection.get_all_images(image_ids=["ami-xxxxxxxxx"])
for k in vars(images[0]).keys():
       print "{0}".format(k)
```

(Or, to print the values as well, you can use):

```
for k,v in vars(images[0]).iteritems():
       print "{0}:{1}".format(k,v)
```

`root_device_type
ramdisk_id
id
owner_alias
billing_products
tags
platform
state
location
type
virtualization_type
sriov_net_support
architecture
description
block_device_mapping
kernel_id
owner_id
is_public
instance_lifecycle
creationDate
name
hypervisor
region
item
connection
root_device_name
ownerId
product_codes`