# pythonic way to print variables in class Person

Tags: python, oop

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    self.age = age

def show(self):
    print(("Name: {}\nSurname: {}\nAge: {}").format(self.name, self.surname, self.age))
```

Is there more pythonic way to show these variables by function show?

I don't want spaghetti code when i have 34 variables in class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print all properties of a Python Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969806/print-all-properties-of-a-python-class)

Comment: Do you wish to print all attribute of  your class?

Comment: create `__str__()` method

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is more Pythonic or not, but instead of defining `show` you can override `__repr__` (you will need to `return` that string instead of printing it). Then instead of calling `person_obj.show` you can simply do `print(person_obj)`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Name: {}\nSurname: {}\nAge: {}").format(self.name,     self.surname, self.age)

print(Person('a','b', 'c'))
>> Name: a
   Surname: b
   Age: c
```

This will display correctly even if you have a list of persons:

```
print([Person('a', 'b', 'c'), Person('d', 'e', 'f')])
>> [Name: a
    Surname: b
    Age: c, Name: d
    Surname: e
    Age: f]
```

Comment: It's not `__repr__` its `__str__`, `__repr__` is used for technical information, while `__str__` - to show data to user, so in this case, he should override `__str__`

Comment: @wasd If you override `str` then the objects still show as `<object at XXXXXX>` when they are part of a collection. This may or may not be what OP wants/needs.

Comment: Well, it was not specified for what actual purposes it is done and I'd might agreed with you if his method was called debug not show, but for representation purposes it is still better and more pythonic to use `__str__` not `__repr__`

Comment: Btw, update your code, you haven't defined neither `__repr__` nor `__str__`

Answer (score 0):

In the case you don't want to override `__str__` and badly need `show` to print, not return data, it's still more pythonic to use `format`. I'd make few adjustment for your code:

```
def show(self):
    person_info = "Name {name}\nSurname {surname}\nAge {age}".format(name=self.name, surname=self.surname, age=self.age)
    print (person_info)
```

In general it's the same you had, just a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the classes' internal `__dict__` property to avoid typing all of the variables twice. Additionally, it's best to use the `__repr__` function for *representing* your class:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join([
            'Name: {name}',
            'Surname: {surname}',
            'Age: {age}'
        ]).format(**self.__dict__)


john = Person('John', 'Doe', 42)
print(john)
```

Another step of abstraction you could take to avoid hardcoding the format string is to create a list of the properties that identify the instance and use them as follows:

```
class Person(object):
    _identifiers = ('name', 'surname', 'age')

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(
            '{k}: {v}'.format(k=key.capitalize(), v=self.__dict__[key])
            for key in self._identifiers
        )


john = Person('John', 'Doe', 42)
print(john)
```