# h5py - Write object dynamically to file?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to write regular python objects (which several key/value pairs) to a hdf5 file. I am using h5py 2.7.0 with python 3.5.2.3.

Right now, I am trying to write one object in its entirety to a dataset:

```
#...read dataset, store one data object in 'obj'
#obj could be something like: {'value1': 0.09, 'state': {'angle_rad': 0.034903, 'value2': 0.83322}, 'value3': 0.3}
dataset = h5File.create_dataset('grp2/ds3', data=obj)
```

This produces an error as the underlying `dtype` can not be converted to a `native HDF5 equivalent`:

```
  File "\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 106, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
  File "\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 100, in make_new_dset
    tid = h5t.py_create(dtype, logical=1)
  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1543, in h5py.h5t.py_create (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-hdf5
110-git\h5py\h5t.c:18116)
  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1565, in h5py.h5t.py_create (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-hdf5
110-git\h5py\h5t.c:17936)
  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1620, in h5py.h5t.py_create (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-hdf5
110-git\h5py\h5t.c:17837)
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Is it possible to write the object to a HDF5 file in a "dynamic" way?

Comment: No you can't write generic Python objects to a `hdf5` file (dictionaries, list, classes, etc).  The file format is designed to save numeric data, roughly the equivalent of `numpy` arrays, and few other things like strings.

Comment: @hpaulj My objects contain fields of type int, double, float, and just a few strings. What I was asking is, if there is like an "automated" way to create a hdf5 compound type out of the object structure I have. So that I can reuse that compound type in a loop and just pass my objects to it. I know that I can have object-like structures in HDF5 by using compound types. But how can I create them with h5py?

Comment: So you are asking about saving structured arrays?  Compound dtype or object dtype?

Comment: @hpaulj Compound datatypes. I am not that familiar with h5py and python since I used HDF5s C++ API before. See https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/compound.html and here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/h5py/compound|sort:relevance/h5py/ZeHD4AGU7Ms/GFNXcWcUWL0J - The second link shows how this could be done in h5py. The code following after `if useCompoundType` is what I stumbled across just a few minutes ago. This looks promising. I am looking for a way to do his `datatype=[('timeStamp', 'float32'), ('value','float32')]` initialization in a dynamic manner. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have sample files that you could try reading with h5py?

Comment: @hpaulj unfortunately not. I am building these sort of hdf5 files (with compound types) for the first time. It should be possible to dynamically infer the type of my values and construct a list out of that though? I am thinking about something like: `1) loop through key/value of each object to infer its datatype. 2) select key (string) as the name 3) use type() to get the type of the value 4) have map<string,string> that maps from the real datatype to a hdf5 datatype ('float32', etc)`. By that, I could dynamically infer the datatypes of my objects... What do you think?

Comment: I havn't tried it myself, but maybe hickle could be useful in your case. https://github.com/telegraphic/hickle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object you want save is a nested dictionary, with numeric values, then it could be recreated with the `group/set` structure of a H5 file.

A simple recursive function would be:

```
def write_layer(gp, adict):
    for k,v in adict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            gp1 = gp.create_group(k)
            write_layer(gp1, v)
        else:
            gp.create_dataset(k, data=np.atleast_1d(v))

In [205]: dd = {'value1': 0.09, 'state': {'angle_rad': 0.034903, 'value2': 0.83322}, 'value3': 0.3}

In [206]: f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')
In [207]: write_layer(f, dd)

In [208]: list(f.keys())
Out[208]: ['state', 'value1', 'value3']
In [209]: f['value1'][:]
Out[209]: array([ 0.09])
In [210]: f['state']['value2'][:]
Out[210]: array([ 0.83322])
```

You might want to refine it and save scalars as attributes rather full datasets.

```
def write_layer1(gp, adict):
    for k,v in adict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            gp1 = gp.create_group(k)
            write_layer1(gp1, v)
        else:
            if isinstance(v, (np.ndarray, list)):
                gp.create_dataset(k, np.atleast_1d(v))
            else:
                gp.attrs.create(k,v)

In [215]: list(f.keys())
Out[215]: ['state']
In [218]: list(f.attrs.items())
Out[218]: [('value3', 0.29999999999999999), ('value1', 0.089999999999999997)]
In [219]: f['state']
Out[219]: <HDF5 group "/state" (0 members)>
In [220]: list(f['state'].attrs.items())
Out[220]: [('value2', 0.83321999999999996), ('angle_rad', 0.034903000000000003)]
```

Retrieving the mix of datasets and attributes is more complicated, though you could write code to hide that.

---

Here's a structured array approach (with a compound dtype)

Define a dtype that matches your dictionary structure.  Nesting like this is possible, but can be awkward if too deep:

```
In [226]: dt=[('state',[('angle_rad','f'),('value2','f')]),
              ('value1','f'),
              ('value3','f')]
In [227]: dt = np.dtype(dt)
```

Make a blank array of this type, with several records; fill in one record with data from your dictionary.  Note that the nest of tuples has to match the dtype nesting.  More generally structured data is provided as a list of such tuples.

```
In [228]: arr = np.ones((3,), dtype=dt)
In [229]: arr[0]=((.034903, 0.83322), 0.09, 0.3)
In [230]: arr
Out[230]: 
array([(( 0.034903,  0.83322001),  0.09,  0.30000001),
       (( 1.      ,  1.        ),  1.  ,  1.        ),
       (( 1.      ,  1.        ),  1.  ,  1.        )], 
      dtype=[('state', [('angle_rad', '<f4'), ('value2', '<f4')]), ('value1', '<f4'), ('value3', '<f4')])
```

Writing the array to the h5 file is straight forward:

```
In [231]: f = h5py.File('test1.h5', 'w')
In [232]: g = f.create_dataset('data', data=arr)
In [233]: g.dtype
Out[233]: dtype([('state', [('angle_rad', '<f4'), ('value2', '<f4')]), ('value1', '<f4'), ('value3', '<f4')])
In [234]: g[:]
Out[234]: 
array([(( 0.034903,  0.83322001),  0.09,  0.30000001),
       (( 1.      ,  1.        ),  1.  ,  1.        ),
       (( 1.      ,  1.        ),  1.  ,  1.        )], 
      dtype=[('state', [('angle_rad', '<f4'), ('value2', '<f4')]), ('value1', '<f4'), ('value3', '<f4')])
```

In theory we could write functions like `write_layer` that work through your dictionary and construct the relevant dtype and records.

Comment: I have managed to build my dtypes recursively based on your answer and my own comment in the original question. I have a follow up question though: How do I write the data into my hdf5 file? The datatypes I created might not match the structure of my obj. I think I need to transfer them into the order, in which the datatype is declared? Is this correct or is there a better way, i.e. the data will be (automatically) accessed by the name of the dtype array? For example, when I have Field A, B, C, D inside my original object but the dtype has the order of B,A,C,D...

Comment: More detailed example: print(value.items()) = `dict_items([('streamName', 'vehicle_gas_pedal'), ('value', 0.0)])
[('streamName', 'O'), ('value', '<f8')]`, print(datatype) = `[('streamName', 'O'), ('value', '<f8')]` - When I try to convert it to an np array with `array = np.array(value.items(), dtype=datatype)` I get an error `ValueError: Setting void-array with object members using buffer.`. Not sure what to do about this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the type of `streamName` has been set like this: (pseudocode) `if(value_type == string) then obj_type[key] = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)` as proposed in the docs (http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html)

Comment: Start a new question.  It's hard to display code in comments.

Comment: In Py3 `adict.items()` is a `dict_items` object;  You can't make an array directly  from it.  I used `items()` in a Py3 appropriate way.  Use `list(adict.items())` if you need a list of key/value tuples.

Answer (score 1):

I know that your problem has already been solved, but I came across a similar problem today and wanted to share my solution. Related: [Print all properties of a Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969806/print-all-properties-of-a-python-class)

Maybe it's gonna help someone. I wrote two little loop for saving/reading an (almost) arbitrary class object to/from an .hdf5-file:

```
import h5py

class testclass:
    def __init__(self, name = '', color = ''):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

testobj = testclass('Chair', 'Red')

with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w') as f:
    for item in vars(testobj).items():
        f.create_dataset(item[0], data = item[1])
```

And then in the script where I want to load the file:

```
import h5py

class testclass:
    def __init__(self, name = '', color = ''):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

testobj = testclass()

with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r') as f:
    for key in f.keys():
        setattr(testobj, key, f[key].value)
```

Works like a charm. The only restriction is that your class properties have to be compatible to h5py.