# pandas astype not recognize fix length bytestring format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

Consider the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "a"], [2, "b"]], columns=["int", "str"])
df.astype({"int":np.int8, "str": np.dtype('|S2')})
arr = df.to_records(index=False)
print(arr.dtype.descr)
```

What I expect to see is:

```
[(u'int', '<i8'), (u'str', '|S2')]
```

instead, I got:

```
[(u'int', '<i8'), (u'str', '|O')]
```

why and what does `'|O'` mean?

I also tried `df.astype({"int":np.int8, "str": '|S2'})`, and got the same result.

Comment: Means type `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means type `object`, [from the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing):

> 'O'    (Python) objects

When you create your DataFrame, although you specify types, the strings are of type `Object`:

```
df.dtypes

int     int64
str    object
dtype: object
```

`astype` is *not* an inplace operation, so your command does nothing at the moment, you need to reassign:

```
df = df.astype({"int":np.int8, "str": np.dtype('|S2')})
```

This still does not convert the strings from `object` however:

```
df.dtypes

int      int8
str    object
dtype: object
```

So when you use `to_records`, `object` is used instead of your designated type.

A fix would be to create your string series separately, and assign it to your DataFrame:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b'], dtype=np.dtype('|S2'))
df['d'] = s

df.dtypes

int      int8
str    object
d         |S2
dtype: object
```

And using `to_records`:

```
df.to_records(index=False)

rec.array([(1, b'a', b'a'), (2, b'b', b'b')],
          dtype=[('int', 'i1'), ('str', 'O'), ('d', 'S2')])
```

Comment: Can you specify `dtype` for columns when creating the dataframe?

Comment: You could create a series with `dtype`, for example `pd.Series(['a', 'b'], dtype=np.dtype('|S2'))` would have type `bytes16`.  I get `unrecognized datatype` when I try to use that type in the DataFrame constructor

Comment: `So when you use to_records, object is used instead of your designated type.` So I can't have the type `|S2` for records from pandas?

Comment: @buzhidao I posted a workaround, seeing now if there is a more general solution

Comment: It would be more convenient to first to generate a record, then assign the dtypes directly to that record

Comment: It is a bit strange to me, that a pandas single dataframe  column can't have 'S2', but a series can.

Comment: Well a single column in a DataFrame is simply a series, but the behavior I find strange is that you cannot cast a series to `|S2` once it is in your DataFrame as far as I can tell.

Comment: It seems when I:  1. use pandas to generate a numpy records, then change the record's  dtype using rec.astype(), some columns will give be completely wrong. for example, some columns are integers before, after the astype operation, they become zero.

Comment: by the way, I reordered the numpy record names. If I don't reorder them, it give me the right result. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I have post my above question in another post, see if you have time to answer it.  @hpaulj, please also help me look into that problem, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791707/strange-behavior-of-numpy-astype-for-record

Comment: Keep in mind if `dtype` is `object`, then the array or series contains pointers to strings (or other objects) elsewhere in memory.  If the dtype is `Sn`, the array stores `n` bytes per element in its own databuffer.  If `Un` it stores `4n` bytes per element.  Array operations with `Sn` or `Un` is faster, but string operations might slower.