# Strange behavior of numpy astype for record

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I am using numpy's `.astype()` method to convert the data types, however, it gives the strange result, Suppose the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys


df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 2, 'a']], columns=["a1", "a2", "str"])
arr = df.to_records(index=False)
dtype1 = [('a1', np.float32), ('a2', np.int32), ('str', '|S2')]
dtype2 = [('a2', np.int32), ('a1', np.float32), ('str', '|S2')]
arr1 = arr.astype(dtype1)
arr2 = arr.astype(dtype2)
print(arr1)
print(arr2)
print(arr)
print(sys.version)
print(np.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)
```

I have test it on different python version, and gives me the different result. The newer version gives me the unexpected result:

```
[(0.1, 2, b'a')]
[(0, 2., b'a')]
[(0.1, 2, 'a')]
3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
1.15.0
0.23.4
```

While the older version give the correct result:

```
[(0.10000000149011612, 2, 'a') (0.10000000149011612, 2, 'b')]
[(2, 0.10000000149011612, 'a') (2, 0.10000000149011612, 'b')]
[(0.1, 2L, 'a') (0.1, 2L, 'b')]
2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
1.11.1
0.20.3
```

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: The code actually runs fine with me. What version of pandas and numpy are you using?

Comment: I'd have to experiment.  Sometimes changing a compound dtype requires a field by field copy.  It may also be an area of current development.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman It seems the newer version of packages did something not intuitive.

Comment: @hpaulj I have found something strange.

Comment: So you are trying to change the order of the fields, rather change their dtypes. I'm vaguely aware of some recent changes that could affect that. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields

Comment: You may need to use a `recfunctions`, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.lib.recfunctions

Comment: @hpaulj I want to do two things: 1. change the dtype of each column 2. recorder the columns. It seems the order version of numpy did them well, while the recent version did something unexpected. After all, I am sticking the columns names with the corresponding data types. If numpy don't swap the columns, but only change the data types, what is the point to write the tuple like specification [('a1', np.float32), ('a2', np.int32), ('str', '|S2')], why not just write it as [ np.float32,   np.int32,  '|S2']

Comment: I'm not saying it's eight.  Just that there's some sort of development going on that affects how multiple fields are accessed.  For now I recommend making a `zeros` array of `dtype2`, and do your own copy one field name at a time. That's how most of the `recfunctions` work.

Comment: In sum, in the current version, `astype` cannot be used to reorder the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#assignment-from-other-structured-arrays

says that assignment from other structured arrays is by position, not by field name.  I think that applies to `astype`.  If so it means you can't reorder  fields with an `astype`.

Accessing multiple fields at once has changed in recent releases, and may change more.  Part of it is whether such access should be a copy or view.

`recfunctions` has code for adding, deleting or merging fields.  A common strategy is to create a target array with the new dtype, and copy values to it by field name.  This is iterative but since typically an array will have many more records than fields the time penalty isn't big,

---

In version 1.14, I can do:

```
In [152]: dt1 = np.dtype([('a',float),('b',int), ('c','U3')])
In [153]: dt2 = np.dtype([('b',int),('a',float), ('c','S3')])

In [154]: arr1 = np.array([(1,2,'a'),(3,4,'b'),(5,6,'c')], dt1)
In [155]: arr1
Out[155]: 
array([(1., 2, 'a'), (3., 4, 'b'), (5., 6, 'c')],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<U3')])
```

Simply using `astype` does not reorder the fields:

```
In [156]: arr1.astype(dt2)
Out[156]: 
array([(1, 2., b'a'), (3, 4., b'b'), (5, 6., b'c')],
      dtype=[('b', '<i8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('c', 'S3')])
```

but multifield indexing does:

```
In [157]: arr1[['b','a','c']]
Out[157]: 
array([(2, 1., 'a'), (4, 3., 'b'), (6, 5., 'c')],
      dtype=[('b', '<i8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('c', '<U3')])
```

now the `dt2` astype is right:

```
In [158]: arr2 = arr1[['b','a','c']].astype(dt2)

In [159]: arr2
Out[159]: 
array([(2, 1., b'a'), (4, 3., b'b'), (6, 5., b'c')],
      dtype=[('b', '<i8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('c', 'S3')])

In [160]: arr1['a']
Out[160]: array([1., 3., 5.])

In [161]: arr2['a']
Out[161]: array([1., 3., 5.])
```

This is 1.14; you are using 1.15, and the docs mention differences in 1.16.  So this is a moving target.

---

The `astype` is behaving the same as assignment to 'blank' array:

```
In [162]: arr2 = np.zeros(arr1.shape, dt2)

In [163]: arr2
Out[163]: 
array([(0, 0., b''), (0, 0., b''), (0, 0., b'')],
      dtype=[('b', '<i8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('c', 'S3')])

In [164]: arr2[:] = arr1

In [165]: arr2
Out[165]: 
array([(1, 2., b'a'), (3, 4., b'b'), (5, 6., b'c')],
      dtype=[('b', '<i8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('c', 'S3')])

In [166]: arr2[:] = arr1[['b','a','c']]

In [167]: arr2
Out[167]: 
array([(2, 1., b'a'), (4, 3., b'b'), (6, 5., b'c')],
      dtype=[('b', '<i8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('c', 'S3')])
```