# How to access class member array in python

Tags: python, ecobee

I have a class member. How do I access "value" of the remotesensor temperature? This is the response from pyecobee module for ECOBEE thermostat.

I tried `thermostat_response.thermostatList` but it gives me error "AttributeError: 'EcobeeThermostatResponse' object has no attribute 'thermostatList'"

I am able to access `thermostat_response.page` and `thermostat_response.status` but not `thermostat_response.thermostatList`

```
thermostat_response = EcobeeThermostatResponse(
  page=Page(
    page=1,
    pageSize=1,
    total=1,
    totalPages=1
  ),
  status=Status(
    code=0,
    message=
  ),
  thermostatList=[
    Thermostat(
      alerts=None,
      modelNumber=athenaSmart,
      reminders=None,
      remoteSensors=[
        RemoteSensor(
          capability=[
            RemoteSensorCapability(
              id=1,
              type=temperature,
              value=717
            ),
            RemoteSensorCapability(
              id=2,
              type=occupancy,
              value=true
            )
          ],
          code=EDGJ,
          id=rs:100,
          inUse=False,
          name=Bedroom,
          type=ecobee3_remote_sensor
        ),
        RemoteSensor(
          capability=[
            RemoteSensorCapability(
              id=1,
              type=temperature,
              value=696
            ),
            RemoteSensorCapability(
              id=2,
              type=humidity,
              value=62
            ),
            RemoteSensorCapability(
              id=3,
              type=occupancy,
              value=true
            )
          ],
          code=None,
          id=ei:0,
          inUse=True,
          name=Living Room,
          type=thermostat
        )
      ],
      runtime=None,
      weather=None
    )
  ]
)
```

This is the defination of EcobeeThermostatResponse class

```
class EcobeeThermostatResponse(EcobeeStatusResponse):
    __slots__ = ['_page', '_thermostat_list']

    attribute_name_map = {'page': 'page', 'thermostat_list': 'thermostatList',
                          'thermostatList': 'thermostat_list', 'status': 'status'}

    attribute_type_map = {'page': 'Page', 'thermostat_list': 'List[Thermostat]', 'status': 'Status'}

    def __init__(self, page, thermostat_list, status):
        """
        Construct a EcobeeThermostatResponse instance

        :param page: The page information for the response
        :param thermostat_list: The list of thermostats returned by the request
        :param status: The api response code
        """
        self._page = page
        self._thermostat_list = thermostat_list
        EcobeeStatusResponse.__init__(self, status)

    @property
    def page(self):
        """
        Gets the page attribute of this EcobeeThermostatResponse instance.

        :return: The value of the page attribute of this EcobeeThermostatResponse instance.
        :rtype: Page
        """
        return self._page

    @property
    def thermostat_list(self):
        """
        Gets the thermostat_list attribute of this EcobeeThermostatResponse instance.

        :return: The value of the thermostat_list attribute of this EcobeeThermostatResponse instance.
        :rtype: List[Thermostat]
        """
        return self._thermostat_list
```

Comment: I would try to go inside the EcobeeThermostatResponse class and see what its attributes are, so you know how they can be accessed.

Comment: in addition, I'm not sure if the "message=" would be a problem

Comment: thermostat_response = some function I am executing and this is the response I get back. Now I am trying to access the temperature from this variable. EcobeeThermostatResponse is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cdn.rawgit.com/sfanous/a674640718e63fdb2f1cb5ed9c2f2466/raw/c8c79fe0a2820b953647cb306f191b46437e5902/EcobeeThermostatResponse.svg), you can use `thermostat_response.thermostat_list()` (as a *function*).

---

#### What if you did not have documentation?

In case you bump into a similar issue and do not have documentation, you can use Python's [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to output all properties of an object, e.g. in your case:

```
`dir(thermostat_response)`
```

More info about that in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969806/print-all-properties-of-a-python-class).

Comment: it says vars() must have __dict__ attribute. Also `thermostat_response.thermostatList()` gives the same error AttributeError: 'EcobeeThermostatResponse' object has no attribute 'thermostatList'"

Comment: @HardyShah It's `thermostat_list()`, not `thermostatList()`

Comment: @HardyShah and what about using `dir(thermostat_response)`? (an alternative for `vars`)

Comment: that worked. Both thermostat_list() and dir(thermostat_response) works.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad this helped! Answer edited to mention `dir` instead of `vars`