# Python: 'Inline' exception handling for multiple exception sources in one line of code

Tags: python, exception

Consider this simple code, which stores a few properties of a `MyClass()` object in a list:

```
c = MyClass()
props = [c.property1, c.property2, ..., c.propertyN]
```

Now, under the hood, `c.property1..N` are realized as `@property`-decorated getter functions, which may raise exceptions during execution. In that case, I want to use a default value ('n/a') in the list assignment, instead of the inaccessible property value.

But I don't want to skip the entire list assignment altogether. So, if only `c.property2` causes an exception, the result should still be:

```
props = ['value_of_property1', 'n/a', ..., 'value_of_propertyN']
```

So I cannot wrap the try-except around the entire list assignment:

```
c = MyClass()
try:
   props = [c.property1, c.property2, ..., c.propertyN]
except MyException:
   props = # yes, what?
```

Of course I could try-except for each element individually:

```
c = MyClass()
props = []

try:
    props.append(c.property1)
except MyException:
    props.append('n/a')

try:
    props.append(c.property2)
except MyException:
    props.append('n/a')

# repeated N times
```

... but this bloats the code and doesn't feel right.

**Is there some sort of *inline* exception handling?**

Perhaps similar these inline if-else statements:

```
props = [c.property1 if len(c.property1) else 'n/a',
         c.property2 if len(c.property2) else 'n/a',
         ...
         c.propertyN if len(c.propertyN) else 'n/a',
        ]
```

**Notes:**

- I have full control over the code for `MyClass()` and the getter functions.
- Modifying the getter functions to handle exceptions internally and return a default value straight away is *not* an option, because in other situations I *want* to know (via exception...) if the property is accessible or not. Otherwise how could I tell if 'n/a' was the true value of a property or the replaced default (fallback) value?
- I have the same problem in print statements using `(N*'{};').format(c.property1, c.property2, ..., c.propertyN)`

Comment: For the `print` problem, use `print(*props, sep=';')`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215408/how-to-list-all-class-properties

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes - as long as `props` already exists and the intended output formatting is as simple as in above example. So do you recommend creating the list first (using the `getattr()` loop from your answer below), and then print elements from the list, rather than the properties directly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inline exception handling, but there's something better: loops. None of your code is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but that's easily fixed with a loop:

```
c = MyClass()
props = []
prop_names = ['property1', 'property2', ...]

for prop_name in prop_names:
    try:
        value = getattr(c, prop_name)
    except MyException:
        value = 'n/a'

    props.append(value)
```

---

If you need to do something more complex than just access an attribute, you can replace the list of property names with a list of functions:

```
c = MyClass()
props = []
getters = [lambda c: c.property1, lambda c: c.property2, ...]

for getter in getters:
    try:
        value = getter(c)
    except MyException:
        value = 'n/a'

    props.append(value)
```