# List all properties defined on a Pydantic BaseModel

Tags: python, pydantic, python-class, pydantic-v2

Is there an elegant way to list all properties defined on a Pydantic BaseModel?

It's possible to extract the list of fields via BaseModel.model_fields and the list of computed fields via BaseModel.model_computed_fields, but there does not appear to be a method for listing all the properties.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Test(BaseModel):

    field: str

    @property
    def len_field(self) -> int:
        return len(self.field)
    
    @property
    def first_char(self) -> str:
        return self.field[0]

    
t = Test(field="abc")
print(t.model_fields, dir(t))
# how do I list "len_field", "first_char"?
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built into pydantic for this that I'm aware of, but you can use `dir` combined with `isinstance` to filter them:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Test(BaseModel):

    field: str

    @property
    def len_field(self) -> int:
        return len(self.field)
    
    @property
    def first_char(self) -> str:
        return self.field[0]
    
    @classmethod
    def get_properties(cls):
        return [name for name in dir(cls) if isinstance(getattr(cls, name), property)]
    
Test.get_properties() # >>> ['first_char', 'len_field']
```

Comment: Thank you, when I tried this I got a `PydanticDeprecatedSince20 ` warning. This works though, it's the other answer in the linked answer in my answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215609/10693596), is to use `inspect.getmembers`:

```py
from inspect import getmembers

print(getmembers(Test, lambda v: isinstance(v, property)))

# [('__fields_set__', <property at 0x114b98130>),
#  ('first_char', <property at 0x15627d4e0>),
#  ('len_field', <property at 0x15627eb60>),
#  ('model_computed_fields', <property at 0x114b6bfb0>),
#  ('model_extra', <property at 0x114b98180>),
#  ('model_fields_set', <property at 0x114b980e0>)]
```

From here, it should be possible to filter out the standard pydantic properties.