# looping over all member variables of a class in python

Tags: python

How do you get a list of all variables in a class thats iteratable? Kind of like locals(), but for a class

```
class Example(object):
    bool143 = True
    bool2 = True
    blah = False
    foo = True
    foobar2000 = False

    def as_list(self)
       ret = []
       for field in XXX:
           if getattr(self, field):
               ret.append(field)
       return ",".join(ret)
```

this should return

```
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.as_list()
bool143, bool2, foo
```

Comment: Why can't use use `for field in [ self.bool143, self.bool2, self.blah, self.foo, self.foobar2000 ]`?  How does it happen that you don't know the instance variables of the class?

Comment: S.Lott: thats what I ended up doing anyways. In my real code, I have like 40 variables, and I thought it'd be better and more DRY to not have to manually make the iteration list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over object attributes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python)

Comment: Related: [python - Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

```
dir(obj)
```

gives you all attributes of the object.
You need to filter out the members from methods etc yourself:

```
class Example(object):
    bool143 = True
    bool2 = True
    blah = False
    foo = True
    foobar2000 = False

example = Example()
members = [attr for attr in dir(example) if not callable(getattr(example, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
print members
```

Will give you:

```
['blah', 'bool143', 'bool2', 'foo', 'foobar2000']
```

Comment: why instantiate an object: dir(Example())

instead of just the class type dir(Example)

Comment: because I'm guessing the OP is looking for instance variables (which might not be present in the class).

Comment: and how do you get the values?

Comment: @knutole: getattr(object, attr)

Comment: How does `callable(attr)` work? Isn't `attr` a string?

Comment: you should have used `vars(Example).items()` or `vars(instance.__class__).items()` instead of `dir()` if you want to check if its callable or not because dir will only return '`string`s as names..

Comment: truppo, please update your answer, see below answer about why callable(attr) doesn't work

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Comment: @Hyuga Hinata.  ClassName.\_\_dict_\_\_["\_\_doc\_\_"] is not guaranteed to contain anything. It just contains the DocString at the top of the class.
   Checking instance.\_\_dict\_\_ can show all instance level attributes (including those not defined in the Class itself, but added to the instance.)  However, it will return an AttributeError if the class is defined as using \_\_slots\_\_, and you don't add \_\_dict\_\_ as one of the slots.

Comment: this even works for a chain of inheritance.

Comment: Important note from the docs:
"Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases."

Answer (score 159):

If you want only the variables (without functions) use:

```
vars(your_object)
```

Comment: You still need to filter __vars__ but this is the correct answer

Comment: really like this approach gonna use it to find out what to serialise before sending states over network for instance...

Comment: `vars` does *not* include the class variables, only the instance variables.

Comment: To add to your answer, specifying `vars(self)['_data']` should give you only the variables back.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix you need to use vars(THECLASSITSELF) on the class itself to get class variables. Check my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for this! I like readability and the pprint() version I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/193539/1896134

Comment: Using this method to specifically answer the OP's question: `members = list(vars(example).keys())` as (at least in python3) `vars` returns a `dict` mapping the name of the member variable to it's value.

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Answer (score 33):

@truppo: your answer is almost correct, but callable will always return false since you're just passing in a string. You need something like the following:

```
[attr for attr in dir(obj()) if not callable(getattr(obj(),attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
```

which will filter out functions

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = Example()
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__',
'__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'bool143', 'bool2', 'blah',
'foo', 'foobar2000', 'as_list']
```

—as you see, that gives you *all* attributes, so you'll have to filter out a little bit. But basically, `dir()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `vars()`, one can use the below code to list all class attributes. It is equivalent to `vars(example).keys()`.

```
example.__dict__.keys()
```

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Answer (score -1):

```
row2dict = lambda r: {c.name: str(getattr(r, c.name)) for c in r.__table__.columns} if r else {}
```

Use this.

Comment: Misleading. There's no attribute '__table__'  in classes by default.

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Answer (score -1):

```
ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]
```

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!

Comment: You sure it actually prints out empty!!!

Answer (score -4):

The easy way to do this is to save all instances of the class in a `list`.

```
a = Example()
b = Example()
all_examples = [ a, b ]
```

Objects don't spring into existence spontaneously.  Some part of your program created them for a reason.  The creation is done for a reason.  Collecting them in a list can also be done for a reason.

If you use a factory, you can do this.

```
class ExampleFactory( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.all_examples= []
    def __call__( self, *args, **kw ):
        e = Example( *args, **kw )
        self.all_examples.append( e )
        return e
    def all( self ):
        return all_examples

makeExample= ExampleFactory()
a = makeExample()
b = makeExample()
for i in makeExample.all():
    print i
```

Comment: I like the idea (I might actually use that in a current project). It's not an answer to the question, though: The OP wants to list the attributes, not the instances themselves.

Comment: @balpha: Ooops.  Didn't read the question.  90% of the time, it's a duplicate of "how do I find all instances of a class."  The actual question (now that you point it out) isn't sensible.  You know the instance variables, just make a list.

Comment: `ClassName.__dict__["__doc__"]`

This will filter out functions, in-built variables etc. and give you just the fields that you need!