# List attributes of an object

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

Is there a way to grab a list of attributes that exist on instances of a class?

```
class new_class():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.multi = int(number) * 2
        self.str = str(number)

a = new_class(2)
print(', '.join(a.SOMETHING))
```

The desired result is that "multi, str" will be output.  I want this to see the current attributes from various parts of a script.

Comment: Virtually everyone in Python names their classes like `NewClass`. You may defy people's expectations if you use a naming convention like `new_class`.

Comment: Even though it is human-interactive and cannot be programatically used, `help()` function helps for getting info on classes, functions, builtins, modules, and more

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python

Comment: python3 -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk; s=Gtk.Settings.get_default(); print({k.name:s.get_property(k.name) for k in s.list_properties()})'

Answer (score 463):

```
>>> class new_class():
...   def __init__(self, number):
...     self.multi = int(number) * 2
...     self.str = str(number)
... 
>>> a = new_class(2)
>>> a.__dict__
{'multi': 4, 'str': '2'}
>>> a.__dict__.keys()
dict_keys(['multi', 'str'])
```

You may also find [pprint](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pprint.html) helpful.

Comment: The issue of __dict__ usage just showed up on r/python.  someone pointed out that vars(a) is equivalent to a.__dict__

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this works on Python 2.7 as well

Comment: To be specific, `pprint.pprint(a.__dict__)` does a pretty-print on the attributes.

Comment: Definitely that `pprint` does NOT work on Python 2.6.

Comment: Note that this only works for user-defined classes, not for built-in or extension types.

Comment: this won't work if the class has a `__slots__` instead of a `__dict__`, and will obscurely partially work if it has both.

Comment: Consider this answer if  `__dict__` does not work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820273/9356315

Comment: this requires `import pprint`, does not seem to be built into the language.

Comment: sometimes `__dict__` may not work for some objects. `dir()` is a more flexible choice.

Answer (score 239):

```
dir(instance)
# or (same value)
instance.__dir__()
# or
instance.__dict__
```

Then you can test what type is with `type()` or if is a method with `callable()`.

Comment: dir worked better on classes with overloaded attribute get/set

Comment: dir(instance) lists a lot of things that you are probably not interested in

Comment: This was the only function that got me all available attributes on the `boston` dataset from sklearn - `__dict__` was empty, when in fact there were 5 available attributes

Comment: dir() is exactly what I was looking for when I Googled 'Python object list attributes' -- A way to inspect an instance of an unfamiliar object and find out what it's like.

Answer (score 191):

All previous answers are correct, you have three options for what you are asking

1. [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)
2. [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)
3. [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

```
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'multi', 'str']
>>> vars(a)
{'multi': 4, 'str': '2'}
>>> a.__dict__
{'multi': 4, 'str': '2'}
```

Comment: `vars(foo)` returns `foo.__dict__`

Answer (score 95):

`vars(obj)` returns the attributes of an object.

Answer (score 43):

[Inspect module](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html):

> The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get
> information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods,
> functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects.

---

Using `getmembers()` you can see all attributes of your class, along with their value. To exclude private or protected attributes use `.startswith('_')`. To exclude methods or functions use `inspect.ismethod()` or `inspect.isfunction()`.

```
import inspect


class NewClass(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.multi = int(number) * 2
        self.str = str(number)

    def func_1(self):
        pass


inst = NewClass(2)

for i in inspect.getmembers(inst):
    # Ignores anything starting with underscore 
    # (that is, private and protected attributes)
    if not i[0].startswith('_'):
        # Ignores methods
        if not inspect.ismethod(i[1]):
            print(i)
```

Note that `ismethod()` is used on the second element of `i` since the first is simply a string (its name).

<sub>Offtopic: Use [CamelCase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) for class names.</sub>

Answer (score 38):

```
>>> ', '.join(i for i in dir(a) if not i.startswith('__'))
'multi, str'
```

This of course will print any methods or attributes in the class definition. You can exclude "private" methods by changing `i.startwith('__')` to `i.startwith('_')`

Answer (score 19):

You can use `dir(your_object)` to get the attributes and `getattr(your_object, your_object_attr)` to get the values

usage :

```
for att in dir(your_object):
    print (att, getattr(your_object,att))
```

This is particularly useful if your object have no __dict__. If that is not the case you can try var(your_object) also

Answer (score 12):

It's often mentioned that to list a complete list of attributes you should use `dir()`. Note however that contrary to popular belief `dir()` does not bring out *all* attributes. For example you might notice that `__name__` might be missing from a class's `dir()` listing even though you can access it from the class itself. From the doc on `dir()` ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)):

> Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an
>   interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For
>   example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the
>   argument is a class.

A function like the following tends to be more complete, although there's no guarantee of completeness since the list returned by `dir()` can be affected by many factors including implementing the `__dir__()` method, or customizing `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()` on the class or one of its parents. See provided links for more details.

```
def dirmore(instance):
    visible = dir(instance)
    visible += [a for a in set(dir(type)).difference(visible)
                if hasattr(instance, a)]
    return sorted(visible)
```

Answer (score 10):

There is more than one way to do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#
# This demonstrates how to pick the attiributes of an object

class C(object) :

  def __init__ (self, name="q" ):
    self.q = name
    self.m = "y?"

c = C()

print ( dir(c) )
```

When run, this code produces:

```
jeffs@jeff-desktop:~/skyset$ python3 attributes.py 
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__',      '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'm', 'q']

jeffs@jeff-desktop:~/skyset$
```

Answer (score 8):

What do you want this for? It may be hard to get you the best answer without knowing your exact intent.

- It is almost always better to do this manually if you want to display an instance of your class in a specific way. This will include exactly what you want and not include what you don't want, and the order will be predictable.

  If you are looking for a way to display the content of a class, manually format the attributes you care about and provide this as the `__str__` or `__repr__` method for your class.
- If you want to learn about what methods and such exist for an object to understand how it works, use `help`. `help(a)` will show you a formatted output about the object's class based on its docstrings.
- `dir` exists for programatically getting all the attributes of an object. (Accessing `__dict__` does something I would group as the same but that I wouldn't use myself.) However, this may not include things you want and it may include things you do not want. It is unreliable and people think they want it a lot more often than they do.
- On a somewhat orthogonal note, there is very little support for Python 3 at the current time. If you are interested in writing real software you are going to want third-party stuff like numpy, lxml, Twisted, PIL, or any number of web frameworks that do not yet support Python 3 and do not have plans to any time too soon. The differences between 2.6 and the 3.x branch are small, but the difference in library support is huge.

Comment: I'd just to point out that five years later (now), I believe all the third party modules that you mention support python3. Source: https://python3wos.appspot.com/

Answer (score 8):

Please see the python shell script which has been executed in sequence, here you will get the attributes of a class in string format separated by comma.

```
>>> class new_class():
...     def __init__(self, number):
...         self.multi = int(number)*2
...         self.str = str(number)
... 
>>> a = new_class(4)
>>> ",".join(a.__dict__.keys())
'str,multi'<br/>
```

I am using python 3.4

Comment: And if you want only the list can use just `a.__dict__.keys()`. However if you want to know if an object has a specific attribute you can use [`hasattr`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to these answers, I'll include a function (python 3) for spewing out virtually the entire structure of any value. It uses `dir` to establish the full list of property names, then uses `getattr` with each name. It displays the type of every member of the value, and when possible also displays the entire member:

```
import json

def get_info(obj):

  type_name = type(obj).__name__
  print('Value is of type {}!'.format(type_name))
  prop_names = dir(obj)

  for prop_name in prop_names:
    prop_val = getattr(obj, prop_name)
    prop_val_type_name = type(prop_val).__name__
    print('{} has property "{}" of type "{}"'.format(type_name, prop_name, prop_val_type_name))

    try:
      val_as_str = json.dumps([ prop_val ], indent=2)[1:-1]
      print('  Here\'s the {} value: {}'.format(prop_name, val_as_str))
    except:
      pass
```

Now any of the following should give insight:

```
get_info(None)
get_info('hello')

import numpy
get_info(numpy)
# ... etc.
```

Comment: yeah this was a lifesaver. couldn't figure out why this i could not easily unpack these lists and sure enough


    type has property "__slots__" of type "tuple"
     Here's the __slots__ value: 
     [
       "nsname",
       "hostmaster",
       "serial",
       "refresh",
       "retry",
       "expires",
       "minttl",
       "ttl"
         ]

Answer (score 3):

- Using `__dict__` or `vars` **does not work** because it misses out `__slots__`.
- Using `__dict__` and `__slots__` **does not work** because it misses out `__slots__` from base classes.
- Using `dir` **does not work** because it includes class attributes, such as methods or properties, as well as the object attributes.
- Using `vars` is equivalent to using `__dict__`.

This is the best I have:

```
from typing import Dict

def get_attrs( x : object ) -> Dict[str, object]:
    mro      = type( x ).mro()
    attrs    = { }
    has_dict = False
    sentinel = object()

    for klass in mro:
        for slot in getattr( klass, "__slots__", () ):
            v = getattr( x, slot, sentinel )

            if v is sentinel:
                continue

            if slot == "__dict__":
                assert not has_dict, "Multiple __dicts__?"
                attrs.update( v )
                has_dict = True
            else:
                attrs[slot] = v

    if not has_dict:
        attrs.update( getattr( x, "__dict__", { } ) )

    return attrs
```

Comment: Let's apply this function to spome simple class:  class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print("created")
    i = 42

  Why your code gives empty list for such class? (I mean if o = C()   then get_attrs(o) is empty) It also did for get_attrs("mystr")

Comment: @ged Because your simple class contains no *instance* fields (as per the question), the result is empty. I'm not sure I understand what you'd expect to see.

Answer (score 2):

### **Get  attributes of an object**

```
class new_class():
    def __init__(self, number):
    self.multi = int(number) * 2
    self.str = str(number)

new_object = new_class(2)                
print(dir(new_object))                   #total list attributes of new_object
attr_value = new_object.__dict__         
print(attr_value)                        #Dictionary of attribute and value for new_class                   

for attr in attr_value:                  #attributes on  new_class
    print(attr)
```

### **Output**

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__','__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'multi', 'str']

{'multi': 4, 'str': '2'}

multi
str
```

Answer (score 1):

As written before using `obj.__dict__` can handle common cases but some classes do not have the `__dict__` attribute and use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) (mostly for memory efficiency).

example for a more resilient way of doing this:

```
class A(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y', )
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


def get_object_attrs(obj):
    try:
        return obj.__dict__
    except AttributeError:
        return {attr: getattr(obj, attr) for attr in obj.__slots__}


a = A(1,2)
b = B(1,2)
assert not hasattr(a, '__dict__')

print(get_object_attrs(a))
print(get_object_attrs(b))
```

this code's output:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

**Note1:**
Python is a dynamic language and it is always better knowing the classes you trying to get the attributes from as even this code can miss some cases.

**Note2:**
this code outputs only instance variables meaning class variables are not provided. for example:

```
class A(object):
    url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

print(A('/questions').__dict__)
```

code outputs:

```
{'path': '/questions'}
```

This code does not print the `url` class attribute and might omit wanted class attributes.
Sometimes we might think an attribute is an instance member but it is not and won't be shown using this example.

Comment: A class can have `__dict__` **and** `__slots__`, so you probably want to try both rather than just the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following Python shell scripting execution in sequence, it will give the solution from creation of class to extracting the field names of instances.

```
>>> class Details:
...       def __init__(self,name,age):
...           self.name=name
...           self.age =age
...       def show_details(self):
...           if self.name:
...              print "Name : ",self.name
...           else:
...              print "Name : ","_"
...           if self.age:
...              if self.age>0:
...                 print "Age  : ",self.age
...              else:
...                 print "Age can't be -ve"
...           else:
...              print "Age  : ","_"
... 
>>> my_details = Details("Rishikesh",24)
>>> 
>>> print my_details
<__main__.Details instance at 0x10e2e77e8>
>>> 
>>> print my_details.name
Rishikesh
>>> print my_details.age
24
>>> 
>>> my_details.show_details()
Name :  Rishikesh
Age  :  24
>>> 
>>> person1 = Details("",34)
>>> person1.name
''
>>> person1.age
34
>>> person1.show_details
<bound method Details.show_details of <__main__.Details instance at 0x10e2e7758>>
>>> 
>>> person1.show_details()
Name :  _
Age  :  34
>>>
>>> person2 = Details("Rob Pike",0)
>>> person2.name
'Rob Pike'
>>> 
>>> person2.age
0
>>> 
>>> person2.show_details()
Name :  Rob Pike
Age  :  _
>>> 
>>> person3 = Details("Rob Pike",-45)
>>> 
>>> person3.name
'Rob Pike'
>>> 
>>> person3.age
-45
>>> 
>>> person3.show_details()
Name :  Rob Pike
Age can't be -ve
>>>
>>> person3.__dict__
{'age': -45, 'name': 'Rob Pike'}
>>>
>>> person3.__dict__.keys()
['age', 'name']
>>>
>>> person3.__dict__.values()
[-45, 'Rob Pike']
>>>
```

Comment: We can also check for the callablilty of each attributes.visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -1):

```
attributes_list = [attribute for attribute in dir(obj) if attribute[0].islower()]
```

Comment: It does not work with class attribute names starting with a capital letter or single underscore.

Answer (score -4):

`__attrs__` gives the list of attributes of an instance.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> r.__attrs__
['_content', 'status_code', 'headers', 'url', 'history', 'encoding', 'reason', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'request']
>>> r.url
'http://www.google.com/'
>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't always work. Also, you write `__attr__` in the description but use `__attrs__` in the code. Neither worked for me (werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)