# Python deepcopy changes the reference to an object

Tags: python, button, kivy, deep-copy

Hi: This is a follow up to this question:

[How to copy all python instances to a new class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744721/how-to-copy-all-python-instances-to-a-new-class/17744957?noredirect=1#17744957)

The problem is that `deepcopy()` is not copying the objects correctly, this can be seen through this working code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global Myroot    
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        Myroot = self.root
        Starthere(None)

        return

class VarStorage:
    pass

VS=VarStorage()
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import copy

def Starthere(instance):
    VS.MyButton=Button()
    print str(VS.MyButton)
    VSCopy=copy.deepcopy(VS)
    print str(VSCopy.MyButton)

MyApp().run()
```

From my understanding of copy, it should print twice the same button, but the result is:

```
<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x046C2CE0>
<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x04745500>
```

How to make `deepcopy()` copy the same object instead of a new (non existing) one?
Thank you!

---------------------- EDIT -----------------------------

After trying `copy()` instead of `deepcopy()`, its not what Im intending to do:

What I get with `deepcopy()`:

- Copied class of VS, with copied items for those which are not objects
  (for instance, if VS.text="text", VSCopy.text will have the same
  contents without being linked whatsoever).
- But, for objects, what I need is a *copy of the reference to such
  object*, which I dont get, since I get a new reference pointint a new
  object.

What I get with `copy()`:

- Copied class VSCopy with refferences pointing to original class VS. I
  dont want this since I want to change VS's contents (thats why Im
  trying to copy it) and still have the original ones available in
  VSCopy.

Is there such a function in copy module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there such a function in copy module?

No, I'm afraid there is not.

It sounds like you want some sort of hybrid deep/shallow behavior, and that's not what exists in the `copy` module.  You either get a shallow copy, or a deep one.

Sorry for the bad news. :)  You may just want to write your own copier, or see if you can accomplish your task without copying *per se*.

(I see you edited your question, so I've answered again to see if I can help.  (Please see my first answer for a response to your original Q.))

Comment: Thank you Ron, this answer actually (iroically) answers the intended question of this post.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `shallowcopy` instead of `deepcopy`. From [copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) docs:

> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>     extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>     the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then,
>     recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
>     original.

You can use [`copy.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) to create a *shallow copy*:

```
VSCopy = copy.copy(VS)
```

Comment: Very much appreciated, thank you! Will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me to ^_^

Comment: Updated the question, the answer doesnt actually solve what I intend to do, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`deepcopy` is working as expected (assuming VarStorages can be deepcopied).  You might be getting confused by the Buttons' string representations.

When you deepcopy an object, it will (by definition) have a new memory address.

This:

```
<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x046C2CE0>
```

means that there's a Button object at memory location 0x046C2CE0.

And this:

```
<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x04745500>
```

means that there's a *different* Button object at memory location 0x04745500.  Which is exactly what you want (right?)--a *new* copy of the first button.

Perhaps (though I don't think so) you actually want a shallow copy (`copy.copy`)?