# Way to iterate though object in python

Tags: python, object, properties

Is there a way in python to get data from object like this:

```
box = BoxWithOranges()
print box['color']
print box['weight']
print box['count']
```

And more compliant:

```
for index in range(box['count']):
    box[index].eat()
```

Comment: is this object a kind of dict or what?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675028/list-attributes-of-an-object

Comment: @marmeladze I think it's from some module because dict doesn't have `.eat()` method...

Comment: It looks as if it is a container that has it's own attributes and also contains a list of items (oranges).

Comment: It's not wholly clear what you're asking, but I suspect your answer lies in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Please post the definition of `BoxWithOranges` or explain more clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: maybe this would be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34452/4481312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to implement the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods for your class. That is what would be invoked when you used the `[]` operator. For example you could have the class keep a `dict` internally

```
class BoxWithOranges:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.attributes[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.attributes[key] = value
```

Demo

```
>>> box = BoxWithOranges()
>>> box['color'] = 'red'
>>> box['weight'] = 10.0
>>> print(box['color'])
red
>>> print(box['weight'])
10.0
```

Comment: I think the key is it needs to take an index or a dictionary key.  I wonder if that means in `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` distinguishing between integers and strings.