# Get list of attributes required to initialize an object of a class

Tags: python, class, attributes, initializer

In Python, Is there a way to get list of attributes required to initialize an object of a class?

For e.g. I have below class:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
```

And I would like to get,

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] # These are required to initialize MyClass instance.
```

may be with the help of,

```
<something>(MyClass)
```

Or,

```
MyClass.<something>
```

There is a discussion to get list of attributes from an object. 
[List attributes of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675028/list-attributes-of-an-object)
But I would like to know, are there any ways to get list of attributes required to initialize an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inspect.getargspecs(YourClass.__init__)`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
...         pass
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(Foo.__init__)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

**BUT** this won't tell you much about *what* `a`, `b` and `c` are supposed to be. I suspect a XY problem here, so you should probably explain the problem you're trying to solve with this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, args):
       self.a = args[0]
       if len(args) > 1:
           self.b = args[1]
       if len(args) > 2:
           self.c = args[2]
```

Comment: How does that answer the question exactly ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: The author requested a possibility to pass a list to a class and use it to init the values. I have provided that...

Comment: please re-read the question - what the OP asked for is "how to get (the) list of attributes required to initialize an object of a class" - which actually means (given his example) "how to get the list of arguments expected by a class initializer".

Comment: Mmh, if you phrase it like that you are right... At first sight is is very ambiguous, though...