# Is there a way to return all objects of a class as a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I'm creating a little game which has multiple weapons. Each weapon is an object variable in the class 'Weapon'. I want to create an array which has every single Weapon object in it as its variable name. Is there an easy way of doing this or do I have to type each object name into the list myself? To clarify, I don't want to list the attributes of an object, I want something that returns a list of objects belonging to a given class.

Comment: Why would you want an array of variable names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List attributes of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675028/list-attributes-of-an-object)

Comment: So that I can iterate through it and print off specific attributes of each object.

Comment: You can use this using `dir`, `__dict__` (if your class doesn't use `__slots__`), a well-placed `locals` call, or using metaclasses.

Comment: You should use one of the structures in the [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) module. So you don't have to take care of removing. Just make the objects add themself in their `__init__()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build such a list yourself, typically by overriding `__new__`.

```
class Weapon:
    weapons = []
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        Weapon.weapons.append(obj)
```

Keep in mind that such a list will delay an instance from being garbage collected, unless you use weak references to track them. Also, there is no automatic removal of an instance from the list; to accomplish that, it may be simpler to use a `dict` that maps an instance's id to the instance itself for easy lookup.