# How to return and see all a Gitlab's Project Issue info using python-gitlab?

Tags: python, gitlab

I am using python-gitlab to access my Gitlab repo's data and get a list of all my repo's issues by running the following:

```
project = gl.projects.get(#my_project_id)
issues = project.issues.list()
```

I can then print this list to see which issues are in the list.

```
issues
[<ProjectIssue iid:1>,<ProjectIssue iid:2>...]
```

I have also tried to get the info for a specific issue by running:

```
issue = project.issues.get(1)     #example for issue 1
```

However, I don't know how to access all the info within that particular issue

When trying to run the "issue" line, I get the following, but I cannot see all the attributes and information of that issue. I'm looking for all the information that should be sent in the API response as defined [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) (eg. state, author, description, etc). How can I see this information?

```
issue
<ProjectIssue iid:1>
```

I know that python-gitlab has defined some methods like the .time_stats() to [list the time stats for my issue](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/issues.html), but I can't find which method to use to find ALL the information for that issue

```
[In] issue.time_stats()
[Out] {'time_estimate': 0, 'total_time_spent': 0, 'human_time_estimate': None, 'human_total_time_spent': None}
```

Comment: Try to call `dir(issue)`
Docs says that this should be possible:   
`issue.attributes['time_stats']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `project.issues.get(1)` it's returning the GitLab Issue as an object (the ProjectIssue class), not as json or an array. I'm not familiar with python-gitlab (and haven't used python in years) but the issue data is likely accessible as an attribute:

```py
issue = project.issues.get(1)
description = issue.description
labels = issue.labels
```

Note that some of the attributes of the ProjectIssue class might be another object.

To get all attributes on the ProjectIssue class, you can do

```py
issue = project.issues.get(1)
getmembers(issue)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41737776/2307873) for more details.