# Get the list of a class's variables & methods in Python

Tags: python

If I have the following class, what's the best way of getting the exact list of variables and methods, *excluding* those from the superclass?

```
class Foo(Bar):
  var1 = 3.14159265
  var2 = Baz()
  @property
  def var3(self):
      return 42
  def meth1(self, var):
      return var
```

I want the tuple `('var1','var2','var3','meth1')` with minimum overhead.  This is being run in a Django environment, which seems to be putting some of it's class instance variables in the read-only `__dict__` variable; a feat which I can't find a way to replicate.

Here's what I'm seeing while playing with it, any suggestions beyond trimming out the `__*` from the dir() or manually listing them?

```
>>> a=Foo()
>>> a
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f48c1e835f0>
>>> dict(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
>>> dir(a)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'meth1', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3']
>>> a.__dict__
{}
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the class and its superclasses are known, something like:

```
tuple(set(dir(Foo)) - set(dir(Bar)))
```

If you want it to be more generic, you can get a list of the base classes using something like

```
bases = Foo.mro()
```

...and then use that list to subtract out attributes from all the base classes.

Comment: I'm going to use your technique in my project, as the base class is predictable.  I'll also implement some caching routine and save it as a method variable, thanks for the set manipulation tip!

Comment: keep in mind that mro() only works for new-style classes ie. those subclassing from 'object'

Answer (score 7):

In your example, `a` is an instance, its `__dict__` will include all variables set in its `__init__` function. To get all class variables, use `a.__class__.__dict__`

Answer (score 3):

A third answer is the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) which does the same as above

Answer (score 1):

```
def getVariablesClass(inst):
var = []
cls = inst.__class__
for v in cls.__dict__:
    if not callable(getattr(cls, v)):
        var.append(v)

return var
```

if you want exclude inline variables check names on the __ at the start and the end of variable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to introspect your own classes, you can do it on class definition and cache it by the way:

```
class Bar:
    parent_prop = 0


class Foo(Bar):
    my_prop1 = 1
    my_prop2 = 2

    def method1(self):
        pass

    SYMBOLS = [k for k in locals().keys() if not k.startswith('_')]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Foo.SYMBOLS)
```

Output:

```
['my_prop1', 'my_prop2', 'method1']
```