# How to know which vars are defined in a class

Tags: python

How can I get a list of which vars are defined in a class, without the classes imported in it?

`vars(obj)` returns all the vars in the class, excluding unwanted bliltin vars, like `__doc__`, `__file__`, `__name__`, `__package__`, `os`, `pdb`, etc.

Comment: Could you maybe post a small example?

Comment: Do you mean the variables defined in a class, or in a module?  I would expect to see variables like `__file__` in the `vars()` for a module, but not for a class.  Also, it's fairly unusual for a class to import modules, but common for a module to do so.  (In Python, unlike Java, you typically don't put each class in its own module.)

Comment: Yeah, I got mixed up with modules and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to get either the `class` variables or an instance variables. Leverage the coding conventions that enforce built-in functions being surrounded by double underscore chars (`'__builtin__'`):

```
class foo:
    baz = 51
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 42
```

---

```
>>> vars(foo)
{'__doc__': None,
 '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x02A35B70>,
 '__module__': '__main__',
 'baz': 51}
>>> {k:v for k,v in vars(foo).items() if k[:2]!="__" and k[-2:]!="__"}
{'baz': 51}
>>> obj = foo()
>>> vars(obj)
{'bar': 42}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doc, I wonder if vars is what you want to use

> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

[I see this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607307/get-the-list-of-a-classs-variables-methods-in-python), that seem like what you want.

Let me know if I'm wrong