# Is eval() always wrong?

Tags: python, eval

I know eval() and exec() should be avoided, but in this situation it seems like the best choice: I'm getting values from checkboxes and textboxes in wxPython and putting them in my config class. Here's how I'm using eval():

```
config = wx.Config()
checkBoxes = ['option_1', 'option_2']
for key in checkBoxes:
    config.Write(key, str(eval('self.m_checkBox_'+key+'.GetValue()'))
```

There aren't any security problems because there isn't any user-input to eval, and it seems pretty clear to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Put checkbox instances into an array and enumerate through it.

Comment: you can store m_checkBox_key's in a dict...

Comment: A dictionary would be my first choice in this situation, but I'm using wxFormBuilder to generate my GUI so I'm a little restricted. I could set all of the object names to something like `m_checkBox['option_1']`, but then I'd have to add code to initialize the dictionary. I'm going to port this to C++ after I finish the python version, so I want to keep the GUI as portable as possible.

Comment: If you have complete control over what strings get `eval()`'d, then it's not "wrong" to use it. There are very little use cases, (this one   included), where using `eval()` is the appropriate solution, however.

Comment: @user1091954 If you're porting to C++ later, wouldn't using a dictionary make this ultimately *easier*, seeing as C++ doesn't really let you look up fields by name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
config = wx.Config()
checkBoxes = ['option_1', 'option_2']
for key in checkBoxes:
    config.Write(key, str(getattr(self, 'm_checkBox_'+key).Value()))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish I'd know about getattr() sooner, I've used eval and exec in this situation before.

Comment: `getattr`, `setattr` are the real alternatives to `locals() globals()` and `eval`

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `config.Write(key, str(getattr(self, 'm_checkBox_'+key).Value()))`? The code isn't valid exactly as-given.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out pretty quickly.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
config = wx.Config()
checkBoxes = {'option_1': m_checkBox_option_1, 
              'option_2': m_checkBox_option_2}
for checkbox in checkBoxes:
    config.Write(checkbox, str(checkBoxes[checkbox].Value()))
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing things more than once. You had to write `option_1` twice, and `m_checkBox_` twice. With lots of options it gets tedious, but still better than writing the config.Write() function each time.

Comment: In my experience, typing somewhat more when you write code to make it simpler to read usually pays off. :-)  That said, if you don't want to type as much, you could consider (1) making a class of your own that holds onto both the name of the checkbox and the checkbox object and (2) making the dictionary the canonical location of the checkbox objects.  (e.g. `checkBoxes = {'option_1': create_new_checkbox}`)  Let me know if you'd like further explanation of these in the answer.

Comment: It seems perfectly clear to me, but I'm the one who wrote it. I posted it here to make sure it's easy for other people to understand, and to see if there is a better way. I'm using wxFormBuilder to generate my GUI, and I want to keep it (the GUI) entirely portable so I can easily port it to C++ later, so I'm a little restricted.

Comment: Instead of `self` having separate `m_checkBox_option_1` and `m_checkBox_option_2` in the first place, it should have `m_checkBox` which is a dictionary with `'option_1'` and `'option_2'` keys, and the original checkbox objects as values. Then we can do code like `self.m_checkBox[name].GetValue()`. The only reason this solution has redundant code is because it works around a design that was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers have done a good job of proposing alternate solutions to the problem at hand, so I'm going to look at the bigger question you asked, and direct you to the words of a smarter developer who [wrote about eval's problems at length](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/).

---

When I see `eval`, a dark cloud descends upon the surrounding code, and I eye the whole mess with suspicion and mistrust until I’m satisfied that its use is justified.

[...]

`eval` is a bad idea because *nearly every time I have seen it used, it has caused unforeseen and unnecessary problems.*

The important bits are “unforeseen” and “unnecessary”. Unforeseen because `eval` has a *huge pile* of caveats associated with it, a list that I can’t even recall in its entirety without some thought. Unnecessary because the alternatives to `eval` tend not to require much more work to implement, whereas the problems caused by `eval` are subtle and nefarious.

[...]

`eval` is bad because it introduces a lot of subtle security and translation issues, it defeats bytecode caching, it hides syntax and other errors until runtime, it causes action at a distance that’s hard to follow, it defeats syntax highlighting. It just makes your code *worse.*

---

You say you made sure not to expose `eval()` to user input. Great! That's a good first step - but as the quote mentions, that's not at all the end of the list of things you have to think about with `eval()`. What brings this answer and the others you've gotten together is that `eval()` is a *false economy.* It is, at the very least, the incurring of technical debt. Like optimization, the two answers to "should I use `eval()`?" are "you shouldn't" and "you shouldn't *yet*."

Comment: I wish I could pick two answers. Thanks, I appreciate getting the background.

Comment: Helping is more important than having my answer accepted. I'm glad it helped you. :)

Comment: For future reference: what the whole tedious post linked to above misses is that Python already has an ast.literal_eval() method *specifically* for safely evaluating literal expressions! http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score -1):

There usually is a better way to write it. In this case, it's [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals), although you may want to have a list of checkbox objects instead of their names and multiple variables in the first place:

```
config = wx.Config()
checkBoxes = ['option_1', 'option_2']
for key in checkBoxes:
    config.Write(key, str(locals()['m_checkBox_' + key].Value()))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
config.Write(key, str(locals()['m_checkBox_%s' % key].Value()))
```

Use `locals()` for locals, `globals()` for globals, `getattr(obj, attr_name)` for getting attr of obj by attr_name.

Comment: Is there any way to access class variables? I'm declaring the m_checkBox's in a superclass and locals() is only returning variables declared in that function.

Comment: I found the answer, if anyone else is wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607307/get-the-list-of-a-classs-variables-methods-in-python

Comment: access class variables using getattr, since class is object too, like everything in python. `getattr(self, 'function')` gives you `self.function` object. You can achieve same result using `obj.__dict__` anyway, but it's better practice to use `getattr`.

Comment: I need to be able to get all of the objects whos names match a certain pattern. I think the best way to do that is to get a list of local objects, and the best way to do *that* is with __dict__. As always, please correct me if I'm wrong.