# How to iterate over class attributes but not functions and returning the attribute values in python?

Tags: python, class, loops, variables

Building on this question 
[looping over all member variables of a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python)

Regarding how to iterate over a class' attributes / non functions. I want to loop over the class variable values and store in a list.

```
class Baz:
    a = 'foo'
    b = 'bar'
    c = 'foobar'
    d = 'fubar'
    e = 'fubaz'

    def __init__(self):
       members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith("__")]
       print members

   baz = Baz()
```

Will return `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

I would like the class attribute values in the list.

Comment: Use `getattr` inside the comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `getattr` function

```
members = [getattr(self, attr) for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith("__")]
```

`getattr(self, 'attr')` is equivalent of `self.attr`

Answer (score 2):

Use the **getattr** method:

```
class Baz:
    a = 'foo'
    b = 'bar'
    c = 'foobar'
    d = 'fubar'
    e = 'fubaz'

    def __init__(self):
       members = [getattr(self,attr) for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith("__")]
       print members

baz = Baz()
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'fubar', 'fubaz']
```