# How to get python class instance variables inside __init__?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance-variables, attr

I'd like to know if there's a way to get class instance variables that are inside an **init**.

I've seen something verify close what I am looking for except that I am looking for a way to get instance variables and not class variables. 
Linked subject: [Looping over class variable's attributes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535156/looping-over-class-variables-attributes-in-python)

Say I have a class such as:

```
class Identity:
    table = "tb_identity"
    def __init__(self, id="", app_name="", app_code="", state="", criticality=""):
        self.id = id
        self.app_name = trigram_name
        self.app_code = trigram_irt
        self.state = state
        self.criticality = criticality
```

I'd like to be able to get a list of with instance variables name like:

```
["id","app_name","app_code","state","criticality"]
```

With something such as :

```
members = [getattr(Identity,attr) for attr in dir(Identity) if not attr.startswith("__")]
```

Im only getting "tb_identity" and not even "table".
But that's not the main problem, I am looking for something like:

```
["id","app_name","app_code","state","criticality"]
```

Is there any proper way to get these variables inside **init** ?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Any way of doing this without instanciation?

Comment: `list(vars(Identity()))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Aran-Fey. Do you know if there's any way of doing that without instanciating an object?
Here are some other linked subjects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675028/list-attributes-of-an-object

Comment: There is a way to do that... but only if you have access to the source code, and you're willing to write some questionable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Identity:
    table = "tb_identity"
    def __init__(self, id="", app_name="", app_code="", state="", criticality=""):
        self.id = id
        self.app_name = 'trigram_name'
        self.app_code = 'trigram_irt'
        self.state = state
        self.criticality = criticality
        print(self.__dict__.keys())

i = Identity()
```

Output

```
dict_keys(['id', 'app_name', 'app_code', 'state', 'criticality'])
```

Comment: While this does work, it also may return methods that were dynamically added to the instance too.  Not there is really a better way, just a gotcha to watch out for. :-)