# Is it possible to run through instance variables in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have this class:

```
class SomeClass()
    var1
    var2
    var3
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to loop through all of these instance variables without calling each variable by its name (like if it was an array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
someobj = SomeClass()
for _attr in someobj.__dict__:
    # double underscore are mostly used by python
    if not _attr.startswith("__") and not callable(_attr):
        print someobj.__dict__[_attr]
```

Comment: Will the instance variables be always read by their declaration order in class?

Comment: No, since they are kept in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`inspect.getmembers(object[, predicate])`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers).

> Return all the members of an object in a list of (name, value) pairs sorted by name. If the optional predicate argument is supplied, only members for which the predicate returns a true value are included.

```
>>> [name for name,thing in inspect.getmembers([])]
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', 
'__delslice__',    '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', 
'__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__','__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 
'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do this. From [looping over all member variables of a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python):

```
class Example(object):
    bool143 = True
    bool2 = True
    blah = False
    foo = True
    foobar2000 = False


members = [attr for attr in dir(Example()) if not callable(attr) and not attr.startswith("__")]
print members
```

Will give you:

```
['blah', 'bool143', 'bool2', 'foo', 'foobar2000']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) standard library module for that.

see [Getting attributes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class)