# How to list specific attribute of all members in my class (Python 3.5.3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, attributes

I'm trying to gather all the `name` attributes of my class' members:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
class Tree:
    config = Node('configure')
    # other class variables...

    def get_all_members(self):
    # tried this option first
    members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
    # and then deleted first option and tried this option
    members = vars(Tree)
    return members
```

I've tried both of these methods that I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python) but the 1st is giving me names of all members. The second is giving the members themselves, but in a list, and I want to have a specific attribute. I tried something like

```
members = [name for name in vars(Tree).name]
```

but that gives me

> members = [name for name in vars(Tree).name]

How can I achieve my goal here?

Just to show `name` is one of `config`'s attributes: `dir(config)` will result:

> ['_NodeMixin__attach', '_NodeMixin__check_loop', '_NodeMixin__detach', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_children', '_name', '_parent', '_path', '_post_attach', '_post_detach', '_pre_attach', '_pre_detach', 'anchestors', 'children', 'depth', 'descendants', 'height', 'is_leaf', 'is_root', *'name'*, 'parent', 'path', 'root', 'separator', 'siblings']

Comment: The code overwrites `members` list with `vars(Tree)` ...

Comment: @falsetru I know, I just wanted to show the 2 methods I used. I used each separately obviously :) I edited my question ,as it was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistakes using `vars()`; It returns a `dict`.

You can use the following to get all the names of all the vars of an object:

```
def get_var_names(obj):
    return {v: o.name for v,o in vars(obj).items() if hasattr(o, 'name')}
```

If you are interested in the class variables, then just call this method with the class instead of an instance:

```
names = get_var_names(Tree)
```

For example:

```
class Named:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class TestCase:
    a = Named("a")
    b = Named("b")

get_var_names(TestCase)
```

prints:

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

Comment: It seems I'm still stuck... I wanted the member itself so I would be able to call some of it's other methods, but I'm left with only it's name. Can this be done with returning something like reference to the member itself?

Comment: You can change `v: o.name` to `v: (o.name, o)`. Now the first element is the name, and the second is the actual object.