# TypeError: descriptor '__weakref__' doesn't apply to object from parent __str__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, weak-references

I have a parent class, let's call it `A` and a bunch of child classes, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc. I want to define a single `__str__()` method on the parent class and inside it I want to access the members of the child class via `dir(self)`. It works, but when I check if the name is a callable with `callable(getattr(self, attr))` I get:

TypeError: descriptor `'__weakref__'` for 'A' objects doesn't apply to 'B' object

The code that raises the error is this:

`[attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]`

Can someone explain what does it mean?

Sidenote:
I managed to get all class members cycling through `self.__dict__`, my question is just out of curiosity, since I cannot understand the error.

**EDIT**

I made a simpler version of the code:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self, par):
        print('10')

    def __str__(self):
        members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]

        str = ''
        for m in members:
            str += m
            str += ','

        return str

class B(A):

    def test_b(self, par):
        print('10_b')

    def __init__(self,first,second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    b = B('one', 'two')
    print(b)
```

But here the code works and correctly prints `first,second,`

The original code is packaged, with the equivalent of A and B in a separate package that is called by a "main" script. The same code in the `__str__()` method of the class in the actual code raises the error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you've tried already?

Comment: Yes. I'll update it right now

Comment: I don't get such error in python-3.5. What's the `example` in your code? and please add the full traceback to the question as well.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo... my fault... I had taken the code from this question on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python), but when you asked to update the question I had already deleted it because I found out that I could cycle `self.__dict__`, so I copied and pasted it from the answer and forgot to substitute `example` with `self`

Comment: I have a simpler example of this bug using dataclasses with slots: `from dataclasses import dataclass @dataclass(slots=True) class Bug: field1: str bug = Bug("hello, world") assert "__weakref__" in dir(bug) getattr(bug, "__weakref__")`

Answer (score 3):

There is something very funky is going on with your code. You'll need to give a lot more detail if there's any chance of finding the problem. The error you reference is raised in one place only ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5eb788bf7f54a8e04429e18fc332db858edd64b6/Objects/descrobject.c#L174)) -- in a method that protects against descriptors from one class (like `__weakref__`) from being used on another incompatible type.

The only way I could reproduce the error (and have B subclass A) was like this:

```
class A:
    pass

class Z:
    pass

class B(A,Z):
    pass

B.__weakref__.__get__(A()) # works
B.__weakref__.__get__(Z()) # fails

# because
assert B.__weakref__ == A.__weakref__ # is true
assert B.__weakref__ == Z.__weakref__, 'B uses A.__weakref__ rather than  Z.__weakref__'
```

Comment: You are right, I made a test with a simpler scenario (see the edit in the question) and it works without any error. The original code in packaged, so both A and B are in a separate package that is called by a script, this is the main difference I can think of