# Set attribute in __new__ subclass with dynamic base_class

Tags: python, class, unicode, subclass, built-in

I have class `A` which subclasses `str` to add meta data via `kwargs`

```
class A(str):
    def __new__(cls, value, **kwargs):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
        obj.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return obj
```

Like using:

```
x = A('test', meta=10)
x.meta
10
```

Now, I want to handle the `unicode` type too, so I adopted the below approach. To dynamically check for the type and use it as `base_class`

```
class B(object):
    def __new__(cls, value, **kwargs):
        base_class = str if isinstance(value, str) else unicode
        new_type = type(cls.__name__, (base_class,), dict(cls.__dict__))
        obj = base_class.__new__(new_type, value)
        obj.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return obj
```

However, that seems to be incorrect way of do it. Gives me a

> TypeError: descriptor '**dict**' for 'B' objects doesn't apply to 'B' object

```
B('test', meta=10)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-533-206366568616> in <module>()
----> 1 B('tes', a=10).a

<ipython-input-528-91dc8e50cb78> in __new__(cls, value, **kw)
     11         new_type = type(cls.__name__, (base_class,), dict(cls.__dict__))
     12         obj = base_class.__new__(new_type, value)
---> 13         obj.__dict__.update(kw)
     14         return obj
     15

TypeError: descriptor '__dict__' for 'B' objects doesn't apply to 'B' object
```

---

I could use class `C` using `setattr` instead, which works fine.

```
class C(object):
    def __new__(cls, value, **kw):
        base_class = str if isinstance(value, str) else unicode
        new_type = type(cls.__name__, (base_class,), dict(cls.__dict__))
        obj = base_class.__new__(new_type, value)
        for k, v in kw.items():
            setattr(obj, k, v)
        return obj

x = C('test', meta=10)
x.meta
10
```

---

Could you help me understand what am I missing out on **`class B`** and how to use `__dict__`?

Comment: An explanation of why you're hitting this error is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481440/typeerror-descriptor-weakref-doesnt-apply-to-object-from-parent-str  Can you explain what else you want to do with the class (other than add an attribute to it?) as there is probably a different approach entirely that will achieve what you want.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? The latter doesn't have a built-in `unicode` type.

Comment: This screams to me "use composition, not inheritance". But even if you feel compelled to use inheritance, why create a new type dynamically (that will be unique for each instance, btw) in `__new__`? That makes little sense to me. Just use the factory pattern, and explicitly define two derived types.

Comment: Note, `x = C('test', meta=10); y = C('test', meta=10); print(isinstance(y, C), isinstance(x, C)); print(type(x) == type(y))`...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this error happens is because of how you create the new type:

```
new_type = type(cls.__name__, (base_class,), dict(cls.__dict__))
```

If you look at the `__dict__` of a bare class:

```
class A(object):
    pass

print(dict(A.__dict__))

{
    '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
    '__module__': '__main__',
    '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
    '__doc__': None
}
```

The `__dict__` and `__weakref__` are descriptors given to every class such that a `__dict__`  is only created when necessary, to save space. It does not apply to built-in objects. It only applies to the specific type it was created with, as each class may have a slightly different location in memory to store the `__dict__`.

One way to fix this is by deleting them:

```
class B(object):
    def __new__(cls, value, **kwargs):
        base_class = str if isinstance(value, str) else unicode
        __dict__ = dict(cls.__dict__)
        del __dict__['__dict__'], __dict__['__weakref__']
        new_type = type(cls.__name__, (base_class,), __dict__)
        obj = base_class.__new__(new_type, value)
        obj.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return obj

b = B(u'b', meta=10)
print(b.meta)  # 10
```

And Python will automatically add it's own `__dict__` descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the ultimate goal here is, but to have a class which has different base classes depending on the initial value, yet still have `__dict__` be relevant, you can try multiple inheritance like:

#### Code:

```
class B(object):

    def __new__(cls, value, **kwargs):
        base_class = str if isinstance(value, str) else float

        class X(base_class, B):
            pass

        new_type = type(cls.__name__, (X,), dict(cls.__dict__))
        obj = base_class.__new__(new_type, value)
        obj.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return obj
```

#### Test Code:

```
for val in ('test', 1.0):
    x = B(val, meta=10)
    print(x, x.meta, type(x), x.__dict__,
          isinstance(x, str), isinstance(x, float))
```

#### Results:

```
test 10 <class '__main__.B'> {'meta': 10} True False
1.0 10 <class '__main__.B'> {'meta': 10} False True
```