# How to loop through all variables from a python class object (without converting them to string)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class Colors:
    RED = '\33[31m'
    GREEN = '\33[32m'
    YELLOW = '\33[33m'
    BLUE = '\33[34m'
    ...
```

How can I loop through these variables **without** turning them into strings?

eg:

```
for color in Colors:
    print(color + 'foo') //should print foo in terminal in each color
```

I attempted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python) question's answer, but this was the result:

```
colors = [attr for attr in dir(Colors) if not callable(getattr(Colors, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]

for color in colors:
    print(color + 'foo')
    //prints this:

    //REDfoo
    //GREENfoo
    ...
```

I also tried this:

```
colors = [attr for attr in dir(Colors) if not callable(getattr(Colors, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]

for color in colors:
    print(Colors.color + 'foo') //error: Colors has no attribute 'color'   
    print(Colors[color] + 'foo') //error: Colors object is not subscriptable
```

Is there any way to make this work that doesn't involve copy/pasting each color?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors) is where I found the colors.

Comment: why do you need a class here? Is there other functionality you need which you haven't shared here? With what you have told us, it seems like this should just be a simple dictionary, not a class at all.

Comment: You should use an enum, then you can iterat directly over th class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dir` function returns a list of attribute names of the given object. You should then use the `getattr` function to obtain the value of an attribute by name instead:

```
colors = [getattr(Colors, attr) for attr in dir(Colors) if not callable(getattr(Colors, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
```

or as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested in the comment, you can use the `vars` function instead to avoid having to call `getattr` to obtain attribute values:

```
colors = [value for attr, value in vars(Colors).items() if not callable(value) and not attr.startswith("__")]
```

Comment: You should really use `vars` here. What's the point of `dir`?

Comment: Indeed. Updated as suggested. Thanks.