# Is there a way to iterate over a specific object's attribute of in a for loop?

Tags: python

Is there any clean way to get a list item's field in a for loop, i.e. directly iterating over the field values without explicitly getting it in the loop itself. Example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple("Person", ["name", "age"])
p1 = Person("Bob", 42)
p2 = Person("Sam", 19)
l = [p1, p2]
for p in l:
    p_name = p.name
    print(p_name)
```

I would like to get the parameter `p_name` from the `for` declaration. The use of tuples is only for example, the solution should work also for objects and preferably for dict

Comment: `for p_name in (p.name for p in l):
    print(p_name)`?

Comment: @Andreas very nice that you've used generator expression, I'm not sure its cleaner than simply assigning it in the next line (I like not having the variable p in your solution). If no direct solution exist this would probably be the best you could do

Comment: I don't see any way this can be done - in fact, why would you want to do so ? Sounds to me like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) …

Comment: @Programmer say you only need p.name for a calculation in a for loop, say it appears many times in the for loop so you would assign it to a variable, now you have 2 variables in the loop p and p_name where only one is really needed. this harms readability and adds unnecessary steps to the flow, could result in bugs where p would be used instead of p_name

Comment: I think OP just wants this as a convenience feature, similar to javascript's object destructuring. Perhaps it could be useful in writing more succinct code - but this is not something available in python, yet. As a side note, pattern matching with `match` in python 3.10 offers a somewhat similar feature - but isn't a construct available in for loops.

Comment: Okay, then, your question should rather be about "Is there a way to get an object's attribute rather than the object itself when assigning it to a variable ?"

Comment: @Programmer I'm looking specifically for something that would work with the for loops. The phrase `object's attribute` could be used to improve clarity, thx for that comment

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a namedtuple, which is still just a tuple - you can use [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)-

```py
for p_name, _ in l:
    print(p_name)
```

Edit: Just to make it clear in this answer - there is currently no way to directly do object destructuring/unpacking in the init section of a `for` loop. The only unpacking construct supported is tuple unpacking.

For ordered objects, you can get a tuple (actually a list) of all values using [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) (or some other method/function specific to the object) and use tuple unpacking on them.

You can, however, approach this as a multi step process - by mapping a function that extracts only the fields you want into a tuple, over the iterable - and then iterating through the result and using tuple unpacking. Use lazy generators to do this efficiently. This is the technique mentioned by @Andreas in a comment, namely-

```py
for p_name in (p.name for p in l):
  print(p_name)
```

You can do the same for any object-

```py
for pfoo, pbar, pbaz in ((p.foo, p.bar, p.baz) for p in l):
  print(pfoo, pbar, pbaz)
```

Comment: I've used namedtuple as an example, I'm looking for a solution which could expand to objects, and also I don't want to restrict the structure

Comment: @Anton.P python does not have object/dict unpacking yet unfortunately. In the specific case of `for` loops, the only unpacking construct supported is tuple unpacking. I assume you're looking for something akin to javascript object destructuring.

Comment: Though I should mention that the concept of "dict unpacking" is available (using the `**` operator), but it is vastly different than tuple unpacking and is not usable in `for` loops.

Comment: What about using dir (such as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python)) ?

Comment: @DonKnacki Already mentioned in my answer.