# What is the equivalent of php's print_r() in python?

Tags: php, python

Or is there a better way to quickly output the contents of an array (multidimensional or what not).  Thanks.

Comment: Should be explained in the question, but:  http://php.net/print_r

Comment: Mark: it's a PHP function that displays on screen the contents of any variable, including arrays or objects.

Comment: print_r is a function in PHP which can output an any dimension array in a format which shows the keys and values.

Comment: see the highest rated answer (not the accepted answer) on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of

Comment: no, it shouldn't be explained in question. it simply requires basic knowledge of both php and python. if you don't understand question - it's not question for you.

Comment: The title of the question should specify this is for arrays only, in PHP print_r does much more because its compatible with almost any input (all props of an object, etc)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The python [print](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) statement does a good job of formatting multidimesion arrays without requiring the [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) available in php.

As the definition for print states that each object is converted to a string, and as simple arrays print a '[' followed by a comma separated list of object values followed by a ']', this will work for any depth and shape of arrays.

For example

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> print x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If you need more advanced formatting than this, [AJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187821/what-is-the-equivalent-of-print-r-in-python/2187834#2187834)s answer suggesting [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 21):

You were looking for the `repr` bult-in function.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr

```
print repr(variable)
```

In Python 3, `print` is no longer a statement, so that would be:

```
print( repr(variable) )
```

Answer (score 10):

```
from pprint import pprint

student = {'Student1': { 'Age':10, 'Roll':1 }, 
           'Student2': { 'Age':12, 'Roll':2 }, 
           'Student3': { 'Age':11, 'Roll':3 }, 
           'Student4': { 'Age':13, 'Roll':4 }, 
           'Student5': { 'Age':10, 'Roll':5 }
           }

pprint(student)
```

Answer (score 7):

here's one you can try:

https://github.com/sha256/python-var-dump

you can install it simply using `pip`

```
pip install var_dump
```

disclaimer: I wrote it :)

Comment: python already has this with `import pprint` https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543327/42223

Answer (score 5):

`print` and `pprint` are great for built-in data types or classes which define a sane object representation. If you want a full dump of arbitrary objects, you'll have to roll your own. That is not that hard: simply create a recursive function with the base case being any non-container built-in data type, and the recursive case applying the function to each item of a container or each attribute of the object, which can be gotten using `dir()` or the `inspect` module.

Answer (score 2):

there is print_r for python https://github.com/marcbelmont/python-print_r/wiki
but it is better to use standard modules

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = list(enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],0))

print(my_list)
```

Will print [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to format `variable` as a string you can do:

```
s = repr(variable)
```

it works regardless the type, and doesn't requiere any imports.

If you want to include the contents of an object in a single string together with its type:

```
if hasattr(variable, "__dict__"):
    s = "{}: {}".format(variable, vars(variable))
else:
    s = repr(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple test views I use HttpResponse. Testing request from form, variable, string, id, not Object

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
HttpResponse(variable)
```

---

```
def add_comment(request, id):
return HttpResponse(id)
```