# Is there a Python equivalent to Perl's Data::Dumper for inspecting data structures?

Tags: python, module, object-dumper

Is there a Python module that can be used in the same way as Perl's [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.125/Dumper.pm) module?

**Edit:** Sorry, I should have been clearer. I was mainly after a module for inspecting data rather than persisting.

BTW Thanks for the answers. This is one awesome site!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Data::Dumper has two main uses: data persistence and debugging/inspecting objects.  As far as I know, there isn't anything that's going to work exactly the same as Data::Dumper.

I use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) for data persistence.

I use [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) to visually inspect my objects / debug.

Comment: See also [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

Answer (score 11):

I think the closest you will find is the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l.append(l)
>>> d = {1: l, 2: 'this is a string'}
>>> print d
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]], 2: 'this is a string'}

>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, <Recursion on list with id=47898714920216>],
 2: 'this is a string'}
```

Answer (score 6):

Possibly a couple of alternatives: [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html), [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve).

Comment: `marshal` is almost certainly not what anyone wants.

Comment: Using combination like this is handy (of course you have to know element is an element of object): 'pprint(object) pprint(vars(object))  pprint(vars(object.element))'

Answer (score 4):

I too have been using Data::Dumper for quite some time and have gotten used to its way of displaying nicely formatted complex data structures. pprint as mentioned above does a pretty decent job, but I didn't quite like its formatting style. That plus pprint doesn't allow you to inspect objects like Data::Dumper does:

Searched on the net and came across these:

https://gist.github.com/1071857#file_dumper.pyamazon

```
>>> y = { 1: [1,2,3], 2: [{'a':1},{'b':2}]}

>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
>>> pp.pprint(y)
{   1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [{   'a': 1}, {   'b': 2}]}

>>> print(Dumper.dump(y)) # Dumper is the python module in the above link
```

```
{
    1: [
        1 
        2 
        3
    ] 
    2: [
        {
            'a': 1
        } 
        {
            'b': 2
        }
    ]
}
```

```
>>> print(Dumper.dump(pp))
```

```
instance::pprint.PrettyPrinter
    __dict__ :: {
        '_depth': None 
        '_stream': file:: > 
        '_width': 80 
        '_indent_per_level': 4
    }
```

Also worth checking is http://salmon-protocol.googlecode.com/svn-history/r24/trunk/salmon-playground/dumper.py It has its own style and seems useful too.

Answer (score 3):

- For serialization, there are many options.

  - One of the best is JSON, which is a language-agnostic standard for serialization. It is available in 2.6 in the stdlib [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module and before that with the same API in the third-party `simplejson` module.
  - You do not want to use `marshal`, which is fairly low-level. If you wanted what it provides, you would use pickle.
  - I avoid using pickle the format is Python-only and insecure. Deserializing using pickle can execute arbitrary code.

    - If you did use `pickle`, you want to use the C implementation thereof. (Do `import cPickle as pickle`.)
- For debugging, you usually want to look at the object's `repr` or to use the `pprint` module.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution for dumping nested data made up of dictionaries, lists, or tuples (it works quite well for me):

**Python2**

```
def printStruct(struc, indent=0):
  if isinstance(struc, dict):
    print '  '*indent+'{'
    for key,val in struc.iteritems():
      if isinstance(val, (dict, list, tuple)):
        print '  '*(indent+1) + str(key) + '=> '
        printStruct(val, indent+2)
      else:
        print '  '*(indent+1) + str(key) + '=> ' + str(val)
    print '  '*indent+'}'
  elif isinstance(struc, list):
    print '  '*indent + '['
    for item in struc:
      printStruct(item, indent+1)
    print '  '*indent + ']'
  elif isinstance(struc, tuple):
    print '  '*indent + '('
    for item in struc:
      printStruct(item, indent+1)
    print '  '*indent + ')'
  else: print '  '*indent + str(struc)
```

**Python3**

```
 def printStruct(struc, indent=0):
   if isinstance(struc, dict):
     print ('  '*indent+'{')
     for key,val in struc.items():
       if isinstance(val, (dict, list, tuple)):
         print ('  '*(indent+1) + str(key) + '=> ')
         printStruct(val, indent+2)
       else:
         print ('  '*(indent+1) + str(key) + '=> ' + str(val))
     print ('  '*indent+'}')
   elif isinstance(struc, list):
     print ('  '*indent + '[')
     for item in struc:
       printStruct(item, indent+1)
     print ('  '*indent + ']')
   elif isinstance(struc, tuple):
     print ('  '*indent + '(')
     for item in struc:
       printStruct(item, indent+1)
     print ('  '*indent + ')')
   else: print ('  '*indent + str(struc))
```

See it at work:

```
>>> d = [{'a1':1, 'a2':2, 'a3':3}, [1,2,3], [{'b1':1, 'b2':2}, {'c1':1}], 'd1', 'd2', 'd3']
>>> printStruct(d)
[
  {
    a1=> 1
    a3=> 3
    a2=> 2
  }
  [
    1
    2
    3
  ]
  [
    {
      b1=> 1
      b2=> 2
    }
    {
      c1=> 1
    }
  ]
  d1
  d2
  d3
]
```

Comment: Perfect! I just cut-n-paste this into Dumper.py and then import Dumper; print(Dumper.printStruct(dict_or_list)); #works, though I change the printStruct to dump.

Answer (score 2):

Saw this and realized Python has something that works akin to Data::Dumper in [Dumper](https://pypi.org/project/Dumper/). The author describes it as

> Dump Python data structures (including class instances) in a nicely-
>   nested, easy-to-read form.  Handles recursive data structures properly,
>   and has sensible options for limiting the extent of the dump both by
>   simple depth and by some rules for how to handle contained instances.

Install it via pip. The Github repo is at https://github.com/jric/Dumper.py.

Answer (score 1):

As far as inspecting your object goes, I found this a useful equivalent of Data:Dumper:

<s>https://salmon-protocol.googlecode.com/svn-history/r24/trunk/salmon-playground/dumper.py</s>

[dumper.py](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506182802/https://salmon-protocol.googlecode.com/svn-history/r24/trunk/salmon-playground/dumper.py) archived from Google Code to Wayback Machine (archive.org)
or
[dumper.py](https://github.com/salmon-protocol/salmon-protocol/blob/master/salmon-playground/dumper.py) exported from Google Code to Github

It can handle unicode strings.

Comment: The above link is bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that works better than pprint, but doesn't require rolling your own, try importing dumper from pypi:
https://github.com/jric/Dumper.py or
https://github.com/ericholscher/pypi/blob/master/dumper.py

Comment: Here is an article that introduces it:  https://web.archive.org/web/20160502035015/https://techblog.chegg.com/2014/10/03/just-print-it/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to return Perl-like dump for API request so I came up with this which doesn't format the output to be pretty, but makes perfect job for me.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import datetime, date

def dump(self, obj):

    if obj is None:
        return "undef"

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return self.dump_dict(obj)

    if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return self.dump_list(obj)

    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return "'{:.05f}'".format(obj)
        # ... or handle it your way

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return "'{}'".format(obj.isoformat(
            sep=' ',
            timespec='milliseconds'))
        # ... or handle it your way

    return "'{}'".format(obj)

def dump_dict(self, obj):
    result = []
    for key, val in obj.items():
        result.append(' => '.join((self.dump(key), self.dump(val))))

    return ' '.join(('{', ', '.join(result), '}'))

def dump_list(self, obj):
    result = []
    for val in obj:
        result.append(self.dump(val))

    return ' '.join(('[', ', '.join(result), ']'))



Using the above:

    example_dict = {'a': 'example1', 'b': 'example2', 'c': [1, 2, 3, 'asd'], 'd': [{'g': 'something1', 'e': 'something2'}, {'z': 'something1'}]}

    print(dump(example_dict))

will ouput:

    { 'b' => 'example2', 'a' => 'example1', 'd' => [ { 'g' => 'something1', 'e' => 'something2' }, { 'z' => 'something1' } ], 'c' => [ '1', '2', '3', 'asd' ] }
```