# Decoding the output of Pickle Python

Tags: python, pickle

I was trying a small example where I was trying to dump a data structure to a file , just like I would do in Perl with the help of `Data::Dumper`. The following is the example I tried

```
import pickle
ff = open('/Users/arunpotharaju/hell','wb')
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
pickle.dump(favorite_color,ff,0)
```

The following is the output in the file `hell`

```
(dp0
S'lion'
p1
S'yellow'
p2
sS'kitty'
p3
S'red'
p4
s.
```

I was looking for more of a `Data::Dumper` style output from Perl, which is very helpful in debugging. Can I make it any better?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540567/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-perls-datadumper

Comment: pickle isn't for debugging - you should use it when you need to load the objects back into Python. Use pprint or maybe json for your debugging

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you could use json to dump a readable version of your dict:

```
import json
ff = open('/Users/arunpotharaju/hell','wb')
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
ff.write(json.dumps(favorite_color))
```

json is not able to dump complex data structures the way pickle works, but it can dump dicts, lists, etc.