# Monitor the state of an object in pdb

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am using python 2.4 and trying to debug a twisted application.

Is there any way by which I can perhaps put a watch on an object and break execution when its value changes.

For Example

To start with A.state="connected"
What I want is a notification or pause in execution when A.state changes its value.

I am new to pdb and twisted so if you feel this question needs more info, I can provide it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of this question and the answer given by @JeremyCantrell is the most useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you watch a variable in pdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668979/how-do-you-watch-a-variable-in-pdb)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139817/python-in-pdb-is-it-possible-to-enable-a-breakpoint-only-after-n-hit-counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look here:

- http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Here is a more detailed answer.
[python: in pdb is it possible to enable a breakpoint only after n hit counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139817/python-in-pdb-is-it-possible-to-enable-a-breakpoint-only-after-n-hit-counts)

Answer (score 0):

If `state` is a property of `A` with a setter method, then you can set a break point inside its setter method and the execution will break whenever there is an attempt to change it.