# How do you watch a variable in pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I'm debugging a python script, and I want to watch a variable for a change (much like you can watch a memory adress in gdb).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @WayneWerner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822154/how-to-watch-a-variable-in-pudb

Answer (score 45):

### data breakpoints with pdb

> ...much like you can watch a memory address in gdb...

- GDB uses data breakpoints, this is made easy with **hardware** support (hardware watchpoints), this typically involves marking the memory pages read-only which then trips an exception handler on memory access. When hardware watchpoints are not available it uses software watchpoints, these are only useful in single threads and are much slower.
- PDB does not support data breakpoints, so the short answer is **NO, you cannot do it with PDB** out of the box.

### printing variables when hitting breakpoints in pdb

For watching a variable when you are hitting a **breakpoint**, you can use the `commands` command. E.g. printing `some_variable` when hitting breakpoint #1 ([canonical example from `pdb` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)).

```
(Pdb) commands 1
(com) print(some_variable)
(com) end
(Pdb)
```

Additionally, you can use the `condition` command to ensure the breakpoint is only hit whenever the variable takes a certain value.

eg:

```
(Pdb) condition 1 some_variable==some_value
```

### other solutions

You can use tracing / profiling functions to examine things step by step using [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) and checking out the opcodes being executed.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
import sys
import dis


def tracefn(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call':
        print("## CALL", frame)
        frame.f_trace_opcodes = True
    elif event == 'opcode':
        opcode = frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]
        opname = dis.opname[opcode]
        print("## OPCODE", opname)
    return tracefn


watchme = 123

def foo():
    global watchme
    watchme = 122

sys.settrace(tracefn)

foo()
```

You will probably need to spy on all the `STORE_*` opcodes. https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Comment: This should be the top answer. Easy, direct, teaches you a neat feature of pdb - the breakpoint commands.

Comment: While it can be useful, it doesn't directly answer the question, which wants to watch for changes to variables, and then break at those changes, not just view the state of a variable at preset breakpoints.

Comment: some variable like `j` seem be used as abbreviation `jump`. I want to pring `j`, could I do that or change the variable name?

Answer (score 33):

For **Python 3**:

you can use **[display](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-display)** functionality of pdb

Once you hit the breakpoint just type

ipdb> **display** *expression*

**example:**

```
ipdb> display instance
display instance: <AppUser: dmitry4>
ipdb> display instance.id
display instance.id: 9
ipdb> display instance.university
display instance.university: <University: @domain.com>

ipdb> display

Currently displaying:
instance.university: <University: @domain.com>
instance.id: 9
instance: <AppUser: dmitry4>
ipdb>
```

as you can see, each time you type display - it will print all of your watches (expressions). You can use builtin function `undisplay` to remove certain watch.

You can also use **pp expression** to prettyprint the expression (very useful)

Comment: If you are watching for changes in a loop, add a `break <lineno>` and every time you `c`ontinue you will get your display shown. Display is pretty handy.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a really hacky way to do this with `pdb`. These commands can be put in your `~/.pdbrc` for automatic loading every time you use `pdb`.

```
!global __currentframe, __stack; from inspect import currentframe as __currentframe, stack as __stack
!global __copy; from copy import copy as __copy
!global __Pdb; from pdb import Pdb as __Pdb
!global __pdb; __pdb = [__framerec[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __framerec[0].f_locals.get("self") for __framerec in __stack() if (__framerec[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __framerec[0].f_locals.get("self")).__class__ == __Pdb][-1]

alias _setup_watchpoint !global __key, __dict, __val; __key = '%1'; __dict = __currentframe().f_locals if __currentframe().f_locals.has_key(__key) else __currentframe().f_globals; __val = __copy(%1)

alias _nextwatch_internal next;; !if __dict[__key] == __val: __pdb.cmdqueue.append("_nextwatch_internal %1")
alias _stepwatch_internal step;; !if __dict[__key] == __val: __pdb.cmdqueue.append("_stepwatch_internal %1")

alias nextwatch __pdb.cmdqueue.extend(["_setup_watchpoint %1", "_nextwatch_internal"])
alias stepwatch __pdb.cmdqueue.extend(["_setup_watchpoint %1", "_stepwatch_internal"])
```

This adds two commands, `nextwatch` and `stepwatch` which each take a variable name *varname* as an argument. They will make a shallow copy of the current frame's local variable for *varname* if possible, and keep executing `next` or `step` respectively until what that name points to changes.

This works in CPython 2.7.2 but relies on some `pdb` internals so it will probably break elsewhere.

Comment: I copied the macros into my ~/.pdbrc file. However pdb tells me: NameError 'nextwatch' is undefiened. I Fall it like this: "nextwatch'(var)

Comment: I am use python 3.5, mac, and it seems `.pdbrc` is not working. Even when I paste the code above into `(pdb):` environment, when I run `stepwatch` or `nextwatch`, it says `__dict` and others are not defined. Could you update your code for python 3.5? thanks

Comment: As mentioned, this probably won't work in some other versions of Python. You are welcome to post a Python 3.5 version as a new answer.

Answer (score 18):

A possible solution is to use [pdb++](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/):

```
pip install pdbpp
```

Then "mark" the object you want to watch with the decorator `@pdb.break_on_setattr`:

```
from pdb import break_on_setattr
@break_on_setattr('bar')
class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()
f.bar = 42    # the program breaks here
```

Here `pdb` will break on any change of the attribute `bar` on any Foo-object.

**Caveats**
Only invocations of the underlying `__setattr__`-method will trigger the breakpoint. This means that `f.bar = 'XYZ'` and `setattr(f, 'XYZ')` will work, but manipulating the `bar`-object will not trigger the breakpoint:

```
f.bar = []
f.bar.append(7) # will NOT trigger breakpoint

f.bar = 2
f.bar += 5      # will trigger breakpoint
```

*Note: `@break_on_setattr` is not part of the standard `pdb`-module. `pdb` is overridden/monkey-patched by the `pdbpp`-package.*

You can also wrap an existing object (via its class) after `pdb.set_trace()`:

```
(Pdb++) import pdb
(Pdb++) pdb.break_on_setattr('tree_id')(self.__class__)
(Pdb++) continue
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm, super simple.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version of [Michael Hoffman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494061/michael-hoffman) solution adopted for ipdb and python 3.7 (changes related to checking of class type and has_key for dict):

```
!global __currentframe, __stack; from inspect import currentframe as __currentframe, stack as __stack
!global __copy; from copy import copy as __copy
!global __Pdb; from IPython.terminal.debugger import TerminalPdb as __Pdb
!global __pdb_list; __pdb_list = [__fr[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __fr[0].f_locals.get("self") for __fr in __stack() if ((type(__fr[0].f_locals.get("pdb")) is __Pdb) or (type(__fr[0].f_locals.get("self")) is __Pdb))]
!global __pdb; __pdb = __pdb_list[0]
alias _setup_watchpoint !global __key, __dict, __val; __key = '%1'; __dict = __currentframe().f_locals if (__key in __currentframe().f_locals) else __currentframe().f_globals; __val = __copy(%1)
alias _nextwatch_internal next;; !if __dict[__key] == __val: __pdb.cmdqueue.append("_nextwatch_internal %1")
alias _stepwatch_internal step;; !if __dict[__key] == __val: __pdb.cmdqueue.append("_stepwatch_internal %1")
alias nextwatch __pdb.cmdqueue.extend(["_setup_watchpoint %1", "_nextwatch_internal"])
alias stepwatch __pdb.cmdqueue.extend(["_setup_watchpoint %1", "_stepwatch_internal"])
```

To use it for python 3.7 and pdb change definition of __Pdb as given below:

```
!global __Pdb; from pdb import Pdb as __Pdb
```

Answer (score 3):

Both existing answers have some essential trouble.

Directly doing it in pdb, or using some hacks to implement watchpoint, can ONLY work when you are in the same scope. It won't work when you get out of the frame.

```
def change(var):
    var.append(1)

a = []
change(a)
```

It can't catch what happens in the function, only knows after `change(a)`, the variable a is changed. This works when the function is trivial, but in reality, the function could be so deep that what is valuable is inside. Or it could be worse, `a` could be returned and passed around, and never change in current scope. Then you'll never catch it.

The `__setattr__` method works ONLY if you can create your own class. It can't deal with the simple situation I mentioned above. For many cases, having a new type of object is not acceptable. For example, if you are working with built-in `dict` or `list`.

I would recommend a library called [watchpoints](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/watchpoints).

It is much easier to use than pdb(if you are not familiar with it already) and it covers way more situations than either of the solutions in this thread.

The only thing you need to do is to `watch` the variable you want to watch.

```
from watchpoints import watch

a = []
watch(a)
a.append(1)  # will print the changes
```

The output would be

```
> <module> (my_script.py:5):
>     a = 1
a:
0
->
1
```

It works with built-in types(including immutable ones), self-defined classes, and even attributes and index. For example, you can do `watch(my_obj.my_attr)` and it will just work.

You mentioned `pdb` so there might be something extra you want to achieve than simply knowing the variable is changed. `watchpoints` supports `pdb` pull up, as `breakpoints()` works.

You need to config `watchpoints` by

```
watch.config(pdb=True)
```

Then `watch` stuff as above. `pdb` will be brought up when the variable is changed. You can `q(uit)` the `pdb` and it will be brought up the next time the variable is changed.

You can refer to the [github](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/watchpoints) page for more usage for the library.