# Pycharm - How do I access the "Watches" pane?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm somewhat new to Pycharm, and I suppose this should be an easy question, but I'm not finding the answer anywhere...

The Pycharm documentation has instructions for adding/editing items in the Watches pane, but the documentation assumes the Watches pane is already open, so it skips the step on how to open/access it. Does anyone know where I can find / how I can open the Watches pane?

Comment: Underlying support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668979/how-do-you-watch-a-variable-in-pdb

Answer (score 8):

In the Debug pane, on the left side, 7th from the top, there is a "Restore Layout" button that unhides the Watches panel.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I bet you got this reply from me after contacting JetBrains support =) There was also [this screenshot](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2465/20121116195956.png) included.

Comment: It's probably in the documentation too, but it's always good to have the answer duplicated online.

Answer (score 1):

To have the `Watches` pane displayed separately and view the configured watches in it, release the Show watches in the `Variables` tab toggle button (eyeglasses button) on the toolbar of the `Variables` pane. By default, the button is pressed.

Comment: Hi, adding screenshots would be great to help point out the location of the button :)