# Pycharm - Edu 2.0.2 how do I access to 'Watches pane?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm started to use Pycharm Edu 2.0.2 for python projects and faced with debug question.

How to access to watches pane.
i  know about [Pycharm - How do I access the “Watches” pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419659/pycharm-how-do-i-access-the-watches-pane)

but my screen looks like 
[Edu Pycharm 2.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJLW6.png)

I have on screen only 3 panels Frame, Variables, Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `2.0.2` version is a very old version (released on Feb 7, 2012), it lacks tons of the features that may be referenced in various SO posts.

You may want to [get the latest version](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) which is presently `5.0.1`