# Where is the watch window in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I've tried for a half hour to find the watch window in Pycharm.  I know it exists because I could access it once but now I've forgotten.  In this article

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debug-tool-window-watches.html

They just assume you know where it is.  If you type in 'watch' on the help menu in Pycharm, you just get a drop down box which does say 'add watches' but you cannot click on it and it does not say where this button is.  If you click on the debugging window there is an 'add watches' tab but nothing happens when you press on it.

Comment: Take a look at the 5m20s mark at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0&index=7&list=PLQ176FUIyIUZ1mwB-uImQE-gmkwzjNLjP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm - How do I access the "Watches" pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419659/pycharm-how-do-i-access-the-watches-pane)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This will restore you debug window

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble finding it also, it was here.
[image]

Comment: Oh, now I get it, the word "Watches" is a pointer to "Variables". Confusing. The whole time it was front and center, I didn't see it because I was looking for "Watches". This is a hint for them to do something about that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul.  When I remove the debug window from the main window, the watch option disappears but thanks to that video, I now know that when the debug window is connected to the main window, the watch window is available.