# How to watch a variable with PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Is it possible to "watch" a variable with PyCharm?
I want to see the values a variable takes on as it runs through a loop.

Or is there something like `console.log()`? I am aware of breakpoints (I don't want to break), `print` and `pprint` :). It would be awesome to click open a list or object for example.

Comment: But I don't get what's wrong with `print()`ing the value of the variable in the loop? To much work? :)

Comment: Well the first drawback is that you have to remember to remove those statements. If you could just right click a var and "watch" it, it wouldn't be necessary. Also, a print statement may work for simple types but lists and dictionaries it's not so great.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint watch, but not just monitor it live - in many cases, it would be changing too fast for that to be sensible anyway.

Comment: Ideally, the watched value would be logged

Comment: I wish they would add this feature too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Watches" pane, this shows how to find it: [Pycharm - How do I access the "Watches" pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419659/pycharm-how-do-i-access-the-watches-pane)

[image: screenshot]

You can just drag variables from the "Variables" pane into it.

You can also watch expressions, e.g. `var + 1`.

Breaking when a variable changes however is currently not possible: [Stop at the line where a variable gets changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955204/stop-at-the-line-where-a-variable-gets-changed)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: To the bypassers: Watches option only appears when you click "debug" the program with breakpoints. Simply adding breakpoints and clicking "run" is no use, as I found out after hours of rage