# How to watch a variable in pudb?

Tags: python, pudb

I'm debugging a python script, and I want to watch a variable and get notified whenever its value changes.

Is there a way to do this in `pudb`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't simply ask for notification any time a value changes (that I'm aware of).

However, you *can* set both watch expressions and conditional breakpoints which should provide the capability that you're looking for.

First, go to the variable list (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), then <kbd>N</kbd> to add a new watch. Enter in whatever variable you want to watch.

Now set a breakpoint at the places that your value can change - back to the main window <kbd>←</kbd>, then find the lines and hit <kbd>B</kbd>. Then let your program run to that line or until your variable is defined.

Then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to select the breakpoints window. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to edit the breakpoint. Add a conditional expression - since your value should be set by now, you can see the value in your watch list. A simple `<variable> != <current value>` should do. Or you can enter a specific criteria.

Now <kbd>←</kbd> back to the main window and let your program <kbd>c</kbd>ontinue. When your conditional is true at that breakpoint, your program will stop and you will see the value in your watch list.

For an example, see the following screencast:

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Can I also watch a class attribute? e.g. `self.foo` or `MyClass.foo`

Comment: You should be able to watch *any* expression - so if it's code that can be evaluated, you should be able to watch it :)

Comment: I'm trying to stop when a class or one of the parent classes set an attribute for the first time, so it is not part of the variable list. So far no luck, still trying...