# Python, debugging: is it possible to capture the moment when the content of a selected variable changes?

Tags: python, debugging

I need to capture in my program who changes the contents of a certain variable.

I know that a breakpoint can be set in the Python debugger in the VSCode environment so that the program breaks at that point only when the content of a certain variable meets a certain condition. But I would need to stop the running of the program at the moment when the content of the variable was changed. About as it is possible, for example, in MS Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: What information do you need to capture? Your question title indicates you might want a timestamp of **when** the variable changed, but your question itself seems to be asking for a way to identify **who** changed something, like a username?

And what do you want to do with this information? Would it be enough to output the information to a separate log file, or would you like to continue using this as a variable in the further execution of your program?

Comment: Answers in this question might give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668979/how-do-you-watch-a-variable-in-pdb.  -

Comment: Something unexpectedly changes the contents of my variable and I have no idea who. This is done by a library (specifically wxpython) and I would just like to specify the place in the code where this happens. The library is quite large and a large part of the operations are triggered by events. In other systems that allow this, I simply set up a variable change check and usually know very quickly who made the value change.
Since Python is an interpreted language, I guess it could easily support something like this. And I wonder if this is true and if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: To rasjani: When I looked for a solution on StackOverflow, I didn't come across this. Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.