# python: in pdb is it possible to enable a breakpoint only after n hit counts?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

In eclipse (and several other IDE's as well) there is an option to turn on the breakpoint only after a certain number of hits. In Python's `pdb` there is a hit count for breakpoints and there is the `condition` command. How do I connect them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer. It's pretty easy actually, there's a command called `ignore` let's say you want to break at breakpoint in line 9 after 1000 hits:

```
b 9
```

Output: `Breakpoint 1 at ...`

```
ignore 1 1000
```

Output: `Will ignore next 1000 crossings of breakpoint 1.`

```
 c
```

Comment: a bit more of explanation please. What is 1 in ignore 1?

Comment: @KansaiRobot - 1 refers to breakpoint number 1

Answer (score 22):

Conditional Breakpoints can be set in 2 ways -

**FIRST:** specify the condition when the breakpoint is set using `break`

```
python -m pdb pdb_break.py
> .../pdb_break.py(7)<module>()
-> def calc(i, n):
(Pdb) break 9, j>0
Breakpoint 1 at .../pdb_break.py:9

(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at .../pdb_break.py:9
        stop only if j>0

(Pdb) continue
i = 0
j = 0
i = 1
> .../pdb_break.py(9)calc()
-> print 'j =', j

(Pdb)
```

**SECOND:** condition can also be applied to an existing breakpoint using the `condition` command. The arguments are the breakpoint ID and the expression.

```
$ python -m pdb pdb_break.py
> .../pdb_break.py(7)<module>()
-> def calc(i, n):
(Pdb) break 9
Breakpoint 1 at .../pdb_break.py:9

(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at .../pdb_break.py:9

(Pdb) condition 1 j>0

(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at .../pdb_break.py:9
        stop only if j>0

(Pdb)
```

[source](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pdb/)

**UPDATE:** I wrote a simpler code

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
for i in range(100):
    print i
```

debugging on terminal -

```
$ python 1.py 
> /code/python/1.py(3)<module>()
-> for i in range(100):
(Pdb) l
  1     
  2     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  3  -> for i in range(100):
  4         print i
[EOF]
(Pdb) break 4, i==3
Breakpoint 1 at /code/python/1.py:4
(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at /code/python/1.py:4
    stop only if i==3
(Pdb) c
0
1
2
> /Users/srikar/code/python/1.py(4)<module>()
-> print i
(Pdb) p i
3
```

Comment: is there, instead of `j`, a variable that holds the hit count for this breakpoint?

Comment: `j` is the current loop iteration. what do you mean "hit count for this breakpoint" ?