# Looking for better data inspector than `dir`

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function in Python to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of)

In interactive python sessions I make a lot of use of the `dir` function, to get a sense of an object's structure.  Unfortunately, `dir` only shows the names of attributes, not their values, so it is nowhere near as informative as it could be.  Furthermore, `dir`'s print out makes no attempt to format the output for ease of reading (IOW: `dir` *don't do no stinkin' pretty-print*).

> Where can I find an "off-the-shelf" data-inspection utility that is more informative, and better formatted, `dir`?

For example, a more useful alternative to `dir` would print the values (suitably formatted, as needed) associated with each attribute, and would format this output for easy reading.  For attributes whose values are callable, it would print their signatures and/or the first lines of their docstrings.

Thanks!

Comment: You may consider using IPython.

Answer (score 3):

Try the inspect module, which can give you all sorts of things, including the original source code for a function, stack frames and more:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
...             self.a = a
...             self.b = b
...             self.c = c
...     def foobar(self):
...             return 100
... 
>>> f = Foo(50, 'abc', 2.5)
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(f)
[('__doc__', None), ('__init__', <bound method Foo.__init__ of <__main__.Foo instance at     0x7f0d76c440e0>>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('a', 50), ('b', 'abc'), ('c', 2.5), ('foobar', <bound method Foo.foobar of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f0d76c440e0>>)]
>>> 
>>> def add5(x):
...     """adds 5 to arg"""
...     return 5 + x
... 
>>> inspect.getdoc(add5)
'adds 5 to arg'
>>> # What arguments does add5 take?
>>> inspect.getargspec(add5)
ArgSpec(args=['x'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>> # Format that nicely...
>>> inspect.formatargspec(inspect.getargspec(add5))
'((x,), None, None, None)'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If , by *"object's structure"* , you mean the instance attributes of the object, note that `dir`**(something)** calls **something**.`__dir()__` if a user-defined method with name `__dir__()` exists, otherwise it inspects **something**.`__dict__` and the type of **something** (I suppose it then  calls the type's `__dir__()` or inspects the type's `__dict__` )

Hence I believe that the instance attributes of an objects are given by its `__dict__` attribute.

But some objects have no instance attributes, for example integers.

So, I think that if you test the existence of the `__dict__` attribute of an object and, if it exists, obtaining its value will give you what you need to obtain : not only the names of the attributes but the objects so named.

Since you ask for formating of the output, I give this example with cPickle (a module is an object, as everything in Python)

```
import cPickle

for name,obj in  cPickle.__dict__.iteritems() :
    print '%-25s  -->  %r' % (name, obj)
```

result

```
load                       -->  <built-in function load>
PicklingError              -->  <class 'cPickle.PicklingError'>
__version__                -->  '1.71'
UnpickleableError          -->  <class 'cPickle.UnpickleableError'>
dump                       -->  <built-in function dump>
__builtins__               -->  <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>
Unpickler                  -->  <built-in function Unpickler>
compatible_formats         -->  ['1.0', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '2.0']
BadPickleGet               -->  <class 'cPickle.BadPickleGet'>
__package__                -->  None
dumps                      -->  <built-in function dumps>
UnpicklingError            -->  <class 'cPickle.UnpicklingError'>
PickleError                -->  <class 'cPickle.PickleError'>
HIGHEST_PROTOCOL           -->  2
__name__                   -->  'cPickle'
loads                      -->  <built-in function loads>
Pickler                    -->  <built-in function Pickler>
__doc__                    -->  'C implementation and optimization of the Python pickle module.'
format_version             -->  '2.0'
```

.

There's also the function **help()** that brings documentation you are searching for.

Comment: `__dir__` is only available in Python 3.

Comment: @Ethan Furman I executed the code in my answer with Python 2.7, not in Python 3.x as it can be deduced from the way the printing instruction is written. ``__dict__`` exists at least from Python 1.5 (http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node270.html)

Comment: @Ethan Furman I did a mistake, you don't speak of ``__dict__`` but ``__dir__``. You are right: there's a description in Python 3 and none in Python 2. But I think it's only an omission, concerning Python 2, because there's the same reference to a ``__dir__`` method in the description of ``dir``. Thanks to your comment, I realized that ``__dir__`` isn't a built-in method automatically created for some objects and not for others; it is a name reserved for the user's usage: if a user defines a user-defined method with this name, this method will automatically called by a call to ``dir()``

Comment: I said `__dir__`, not `__dict__`.  However, it seems `__dir__` was added in 2.6, so thanks for the feedback.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html)

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(object_you_want_to_see)
```

Comment: doesn't `inspect` or `dir` class attributes or object members, just runs the object's `.str()` or `.repr()` method and formats it.